# Order of JavaScript <script> tag executions not guaranteed in major browsers?

Tags: javascript, browser

Is it true that there are no guarantees across major browsers that the following script tags will always execute both sequentially AND in order of declaration? i.e. should I assume that the following code will not always yield x == 'ab' in alert?

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //tag A
      var x = x || ''; x += 'a';
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //tag B
      var x = x || ''; x += 'b';
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       alert('x='+x);
    <script>
</body>
```

... and it's possible that x will instead be one of the following:

1. 'ba' - if tag B executes before A
2. 'a' or 'b' - race condition where A and B execute in parallel (Though seems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663125/is-javascript-multithreaded/1663172#1663172) thread clearly says that browsers only allocate a single thread of JS)

Comment: I am familiar with this being a problem for linked js src files, bu not for script blocks as defined in the question. e.g. <script src="...."></script><script>code that relies on previously linked file</script> will fail 9 times out of ten (cached js file being 1 in 10)

Comment: Browsers should most definitely be executing these scripts both sequentially and in order.  Has your experience been to the contrary?

Comment: @JonathanFingland: It's not a problem for linked JS files either, unless they use `async` or `defer` attributes, or themselves write/add further scripts.

Comment: Must read: http://html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading

Comment: I also had a case described by @JonathanFingland ("`<script src="...."></script><script>code that relies on previously linked file</script>`") - the src was loading jQuery, the following script block relied on it - but found `$` to be undefined. Added a `setTimeout(..., 0)` 'around' the script block code to give jQuery time to load - worked. So something is happening here that I wouldn't expect.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The execution order of these non-dynamically added `script` tags should be purely `sequentially` in every browser:

Snippet from [this link](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch12_03.htm):

> JavaScript statements that appear
>   between `<script>` and `</script>` tags
>   are executed in order of appearance;
>   when more than one script appears in a
>   file, the scripts are executed in the
>   order in which they appear.

However, things could change as soon as you're:

- triggering *asynchronous* processing through your own code (not in this example)
- [adding script tags dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94141/javascripts-document-write-inline-script-execution-order/94744#94744)
- using the `defer` [attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp).

Comment: This is even true for nested `document.write` scripts, see [document.write script execution order](http://kangax.github.com/jstests/document_write_script_execution_order_test/) by kangax.

Comment: I failed so hard today on this. My website was fine, untill I put the static on a CDN and the load order was not guaranteed anymore (somehow my original static server served on FIFO(first in first out)). Tip: don't load multiple dependent js files by adding script tags dynamically. Then just concat the files or so. Thanks guys!

Comment: Specially, multiple `<script>` locate in different deep element of bod, is the `order` a `Depth-first order` or `Breadth-first order` ?