# ReferenceError: Vue is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to re-build my portfolio and migrate it to Vue. This is my second project working with Vue, and I'm not sure why but I keep getting an error that Vue is not defined in my main.js file (which is where I'm building all of my vue components, etc.)
`ReferenceError: Vue is not defined`
[Here is a link to the project repo on gitlab](https://gitlab.com/KayDeeJay/kevins-portfolio)
Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because main.js is appearing before vuedev.js in your index.html.

https://gitlab.com/KayDeeJay/kevins-portfolio/blob/master/index.html#L9-10

Related issue: [Order of JavaScript <script> tag executions not guaranteed in major browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231616/order-of-javascript-script-tag-executions-not-guaranteed-in-major-browsers)

> JavaScript statements that appear between `<script>` and `</script>` tags are executed in order of appearance; when more than one script appears in a file, the scripts are executed in the order in which they appear.

Comment: Well, that got me a different error, which is progress! Now I'm seeing `[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #page`

Comment: And that problem I was able to fix by moving the <script> tags below the div with id "#page". Is it in any way problematic to have the script tags within the body tag, rather than the head tag?

Comment: I don't have much experience with Vue sorry. You should be able to leave vuedev.js in the head. 

Main.js is erroring because it's trying to run that code straight away, before the div element is made. You should be able to put it in the head then wrap that code into an init function from the body so you can call it when the div element exists.