# Javascript; Calling src within the script?

Tags: javascript, rotation

I'm making a simple affiliate ad rotation JavaScript. I'm still new to JavaScript and don't fully understand it so bear with me.

Google's adsense is split into 2 parts, one to set the variables, and the next to get the script. Then Amazon has an iframe to get it's ad's. All I want to do is use a random number from 1 to 2 (will be larger later) that will randomly select one of them to display on my localhost.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
/* Custom footer */

select = rand(2);

if(select == 1){
     google_ad_client = "-----------";
     google_ad_slot = "---------";
     google_ad_width = ---;
     google_ad_height = --;

     //get this google 
     <script ...src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js

} else {
         <iframe src="http://rcm.amazon.com/e/cm?t=------&o=1&p=48&l=ur1&category=amazonhomepage&f=ifr" width="728" height="90" scrolling="no" border="0" marginwidth="0" style="border:none;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking...

Comment: First make sure what you are trying to do doesn't break any adsense policies.  Any modification to their generated script code is in violation with their policy.

Comment: Breaking their policy? I thought that meant modifying the data from their show_ads.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `document.write("<html>or text</html")` to write html out to the page, though for the iframe i would suggest putting it inside another div

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
/* Custom footer */

var select = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);

if(select == 1){
     google_ad_client = "-----------";
     google_ad_slot = "---------";
     google_ad_width = ---;
     google_ad_height = --;

     //get this google 
     document.write("<script ...src='http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js' />");

} else {
     document.getElementById('adContainer').innerHTML('<iframe src="http://rcm.amazon.com/e/cm?t=------&o=1&p=48&l=ur1&category=amazonhomepage&f=ifr" width="728" height="90" scrolling="no" border="0" marginwidth="0" style="border:none;" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `document.write("stringtowritetodocument");` in order to get JavaScript to write anything to the document.

So, inside your `if`:

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>');
```

Also, once this grows in complexity, you may need to look out for this:
[JavaScript's document.write Inline Script Execution Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94141/javascripts-document-write-inline-script-execution-order)

What you want may also be accomplished better with some server-side code, if that is available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Document.Write()`?

e.g. `Document.Write("<p>Your HTML Here</p");`