# Internet Explorer tries to run jQuery before loading the library

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, dom

I have a small script

```
document.write("<html><head><script src='/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'></scr"
         + "ipt><script>alert($"+"().jquery);</scri" + "pt></head></html>");
```

But I get a `$ is undefined` in Internet Explorer. I think it tries to run the script before loading the library.

However this runs in Firefox. Please help.

Edit: I open a new window and write to that window's document.

Comment: Where is this running in? Aren't you nesting two HTML documents?

Comment: I open a new window and write to that window's document.

Comment: Can you throw an example on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 8):

What's wrong with creating the `<script>` tag the proper way? `document.write` is evil, end of discussion.

Try with this:

```
var load_script = function(options) {
  options.owner_document = options.owner_document || document;

  var script_tag = options.owner_document.createElement('script');
  script_tag.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  script_tag.setAttribute('src', options.src);
  script_tag.onload = function() {
    script_tag.onreadystatechange = null;
    options.callback && options.callback();
  };
  script_tag.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (script_tag.readyState == 'loaded' || script_tag.readyState == 'complete') {
      script_tag.onload = null;
      options.callback && options.callback();
    }
  };
  options.owner_document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script_tag);
};
```

as you see, there's a simple API on that snippet:
**src** - source of the script
**owner_document** - document where the script will be inserted, defaults to the current document where the script is running from
**callback** - function to run after the script has loaded, anything that requires the `src` script is safe to be run inside this closure.

example usage:

```
// sample loading of jQuery
load_script({
  src: '/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js',
  callback: function() {
    // jQuery is available at this point, run your code.

  }
});
```

alternatively, you can use loaders like [requiere.js](http://requirejs.org) and [LABjs](http://labjs.com/)

Answer (score 4):

The thing is that you have unintentionally triggered IE to load your scripts in a non-blocking way. Read this for more information: [Loading JavaScript without blocking](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/23/loading-javascript-without-blocking/).

The page suggests that you use this code to get notified when the script has finished loading:

```
//Internet Explorer only
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js";
script.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
            script.readyState == "complete"){
        script.onreadystatechange = null;
        // Your code goes here.
        alert("Script is ready!");
    }
};
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 1):

try running your second script on page load(`window.onload`) , or try inserting the script in the body, not in the head section.
try :

```
document.write("<html><head><script src='/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'></scr"
     + "ipt><script>window.onload = function(){alert($"+"().jquery);};</scri" + "pt></head></html>");
```

the browser won't load the library instantly (unless it has it in its cache) so your script might get called before the library is loaded.

Comment: waw... 4 down votes and counting :)). at least one vote came with a comment too

Comment: you sound convincing, but isn't it a little different? A browser loads and runs script tags in a synchronous manner so that using `$(document).ready()` is possible after you load `jquery*.js`. I say you're wrong

Comment: He is not wrong, it looks like MSIE does handle the parsing of documents created using `document.write()` not the expected way. Per default script's should not be deferred, but in that case they are.

Answer (score 1):

See this solution:
[JavaScript's document.write Inline Script Execution Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94141/javascripts-document-write-inline-script-execution-order/120165#120165)

(also note the comment, it's important)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a recursive function that waits for the jquery library to load and then executes any code once the library is loaded.  You probably want to add a conditional that breaks out of the recursion if it gets too deep.

```
 document.write("<html><head><script src='/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'></scr"+ "ipt><script type='text/javascript'>var wait_for_jQuery = function() {if (typeof $ === 'undefined') {setTimeout('wait_for_jQuery()', 1000);} else {alert($"+"().jquery);}};  wait_for_jQuery(); </scri" + "pt></head></html>");
```

Working example here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/YqTgM/36/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the script tag running your code to the end of the body tag? According to [Yahoo's best practices](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) (creators of YSlow):

> The problem caused by scripts is that
>   they block parallel downloads. The
>   HTTP/1.1 specification suggests that
>   browsers download no more than two
>   components in parallel per hostname.
>   If you serve your images from multiple
>   hostnames, you can get more than two
>   downloads to occur in parallel. While
>   a script is downloading, however, the
>   browser won't start any other
>   downloads, even on different
>   hostnames.

So the result would look like...

```
document.write("<html><head><script src='/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'></scr"
     + "ipt></head><body><script>alert($"+"().jquery);</scri" + "pt></body></html>");
```

Although I would also advocate not using document.write().

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try?

http://jsfiddle.net/MP75r/

Answer (score 0):

If you want simplified conditional loading of jQuery, there are many options out there already; no need to reinvent the wheel. Already mentioned are RequireJS and [LabJS](http://labjs.com/). I am using [Head.js](http://headjs.com/) and it couldn't be easier to accomplish the goal of non-blocking loading while respecting execution order.

Answer (score 0):

you  are just creating a tag to reference jQuery, and as soon as its created next statement is an alert. There is no way specified by you that alert statement should run after after file load.

Answer (score -1):

A simple timer should do it.

```
(function(){
  function wait() {
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        setTimeout(wait, 50);            
    } else {
        run(); // your code to execute
    }
  }

  wait();
})();
```

Example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/madr/Gtafq/

Answer (score -2):

Inside the `<script></script>` tag wrap your code in a document ready function so the libraries are loaded before running.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   // put all your jQuery code here
 });
```

Comment: You can't use the `$` function to delay the execution of the `$` function until the `$` function is loaded, just as (if you lock yourself out) you can't go inside to get the key so that you can let yourself in.

Comment: Using the jQuery library to wait for the jQuery library to load when it hasn't been loaded yet?

Comment: Point well taken.  It's not be the best solution but what about loading JQuery from a CDN instead?  At least you would have a better chance of hitting a cached version.

Comment: Even if you had a better chance, you couldn't guarantee that it would work for everyone.