# recursive document.write in IE browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

In javascript/jscript. We can use `document.write("<script...")`  to load a html fragment into the document. But when there is another document.write inside the html fragment. Some browser do recursive script loading but some not(IE).

Here is a example. The document.write inject one external script(js1.js) and an inline script into the document. The inline script will call a variable defined in js1.js. That require the browser to load js1.js before the inline script was executed. In gecko and safari based brwoser. It works. But in IE browser, it sucks.

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
    <textarea id="tagContent" style="width:600px;height:400px;">
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='js1.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert(xx);
</script>
    </textarea>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(document.getElementById("tagContent").value);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**js1.js**

```
window.xx = "ssss";
```

I want to find a way to do the injection in IE. Any idea is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript's document.write Inline Script Execution Order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94141/javascripts-document-write-inline-script-execution-order)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to declare your script element and add it in a structured way:

```
var myScript = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
myScript.src='js1.js';
myScript.type='text/javascript';

document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0].appendChild(myScript);
```

Happy coding.

B

Comment: Thanks Brian. But in my case I can't change the two <script> tag. Those html codes were provided by the 3rd party.

Comment: We must write the HTML code using document.write. Because the written code might contain script tags and "document.write" recursively. The document will be cleaned up if those code run after page was loaded.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use an iframe or something external - I've never heard of a self evaluating document.write, where the result of the .write is parsed and evaluated as a loaded script...

Comment: Are you getting any specific error from IE that might provide more details?