# Async and document ready

Tags: jquery, html

I try to optimize my pages by putting some `async` attributes on my scripts. It seems to break my javascript since `$(document).ready` is executed before the all scripts are loaded!

I saw that I can resolve my problem by putting `$(window).load` instead of `$(document).ready` but I was wondering if there is a better solution. 
This solution trigger 2 problems in my case :

1. I have to change all `$(document).ready` and tell all the developpers to not use it anymore
2. The scripts will be executed after all images are loaded. My website has a lot of heavy images and I really need some scripts to be executed ASAP after dom is ready.

Do you have some magic tricks? Maybe putting all scripts at the end? use `defer` instead of `async`?

Comment: document ready calls are executed also for scripts using document.ready after jQuery detected the document ready state. On a site where jQuery is used, try to use the following after all resources are loaded:
```$(document).ready(function () {console.log('READY');});```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

After some extensive research, I can definitely say that putting scripts at the end of the page is THE best practice.

Yahoo agrees with me : http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Google don't talk about this practice and seems to prefer async scripts : https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rtt#PreferAsyncResources

IMHO, putting script at the end of the page has several benefits over async/defer:

- It will work for all browser (yes, even IE ;) )
- You guarantee the execution order
- You do not need to use `$(document).ready` or `$(window).load`
- Your scripts can execute before your images are loaded
- As async/defer, your page will be displayed quicker
- When the DOM trigger the ready event, all scripts are loaded
- Can be optimized by merging all js in one file without problem (by a tool like mod_pagespeed)

The only drawback that I can see is that the browser won't be able to parallelize the downloads. 
One good reason to use async/defer instead is when you have a script that is completly independant ( do not need to rely on the execution order) and that don't need to be executed at a specific timing. Example : google analytics.

Comment: It does not fully guarantee the execution by putting them down in the DOM. If you got too much JavaScript and / or HTML for the browser, you need requirejs or any other system loader like that. I saw design that worked only with compressed JavaScript, because it was too much. It was an bootstrap 3.x respsonsive theme with effects while scrolling down the page.

Comment: the only valuable argment to not use defer in 2012 was, as said by Yahoo :  Firefox doesn't support the DEFER attribute. However now in 2020 you can use the defer mode every where : https://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer

Comment: See my answer below. Jquery has a built in call to help out with this exact issue.

Answer (score 6):

`defer` would definitely help here.

`defer` is generally better than `async` because it:

- loads asynchronously (just like `async`)
- guarantees the execution order (unlike `async`)
- executes at the end (unlike `async` that executes in parallel when the page is still loading and it actually *halts* the dom-parsing!)
- jquery `ready` fires *after* the "deferred" scripts have been loaded (this is what you're asking)

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39711009/56621) has a very nice picture illustrating defer/async load order, super-understandable.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't want to use a script loader, you could use the following approach which would allow you to leave your $(document).ready scripts in place - modified as follows:

```
$(()=>{

    function checkAllDownloads() {
        // Ensure your namespace exists.
        window.mynamespace = window.mynamespace || {};

        // Have each of your scripts setup a variable in your namespace when the download has completed.
        // That way you can set async on all your scripts except jquery.
        // Use the document ready event - this code - to check if all your scripts have downloaded.
        if (window.mynamespace.script1 && window.mynamespace.script2){

          // Proceed with page initialisation now that all scripts have been downloaded.
          // [ Add your page initialisation code here ].
          return;
        } 
        // Not all downloads have completed.
        // Schedule another check to give the async downloads time to complete.
        setTimeout(checkAllDownloads, 500);
    }

    // check if it is safe to initialise the page by checking if all downloads have completed.
    checkAllDownloads();

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well recently and resolved it using the built in "getScript" Call (jQuery)

**Reference:** https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

**Example:**

```
     $.getScript("[Your local file path or external URL]",
          function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
            
          //Code to run after the script has been loaded
        
      });
```