# Issue with jQuery uncaught reference

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, typeerror

Here is my website 
If I open it in Chrome sometime I don't see the menu function on hover.
In the console I get this

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined /catalog/view/javascript/journal/pnotify/jquery.pnotify.min.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined /catalog/view/javascript/journal/cookie.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined /catalog/view/javascript/jquery/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js:82
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined /catalog/view/javascript/jquery/tabs.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I know this is an old error and I have seen several questions on SO,
but none of them helped me

If you open the same site in Firefox , it warns you about some unresponsive JavaScript and once you click OK it works fine, I am not really sure that what is the issue behind this, if it is jQuery issue, it would be difficult to go in each file and debug it, 
Anyone who can assist me by looking at console logs?

Comment: Try wrapping your custom code in the `ready` function for jQuery http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @RobSchmuecker well i guess its not the custom code but already created js file by some dev

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886614/uncaught-referenceerror-jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: @Anonymous in my question I clearly mentioned that I have seen questions on SO,similar to it

Comment: @user1765876 Either way, it is a duplicate.  The other option would be to cause it as a typographical error, which it may be.  But, the main point is that it is the same exact error.  Knowing **why** the error occurs allows you to find the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set the async attribute to jQuery include [script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) like `<script async src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>` remove it.

```
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

In normal circumstances the scripts are executed in the order in which they are included. But since you have used the `async` flag the execution of core jQuery library will be asynchronous. So there are chances that it will be executed after the rest of script files which needs jQuery library.

Comment: in which file?you are talking about

Comment: @user1765876 in the view source of your file

Comment: please edit your comment to NOT include website name, thanks,

Comment: that worked but there are some other files as well having async in it..jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js, so async is helpful?

Comment: I don't think in your case you should use it... because when dom ready fires the async files may not be loaded...(not sure - need confirmation)

Comment: @user1765876 infact dom ready handler does not seems to be working with async loading - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043656/async-and-document-ready

Answer (score 2):

Move this line without `async`

```
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

to the top of your javascript included files
and make sure there is no conflict between jquery and other library

Answer (score 0):

Hi i was also having the same problem. I got the solution too in my way. you just look at my code. if it does the same thing on your project correct it.

```
function fill_grid()
{
 //some of my work
 var para=new Array();
 para[0]="id";
 para[1]=retcond("");
}
function retcond(posid)
{
//
var cond="where pfid="'19282'";
retcond=cond;
return retcond;
}
```

The above code was working fine at the first button_click. but at second click gave me the same error you got. now I changed the "retcond()" function into,

```
function retcond(posid)
{
//
return cond;  
}
```

Since i didn't declare the variable name, it made me troubled. now it solved. hope this can give you any idea.