# Does jQuery $(document).ready ALWAYS wait for async scripts?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, document-ready

I was wondering if jQuery's `$(document).ready()` function is always waiting also for asynchronously loaded scripts:

**HTML**

```
<script async src="...">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //is the script always loaded at this point?
});
```

I couldn't find any confirmation of this assumption in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). Is there a source where this is explicitly regulated?

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11043656/464709), `ready()` won't wait for async scripts.

Comment: This will wait, i think
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){});

Comment: It can also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043656/async-and-document-ready

Comment: @Superdrac, yup, that's my link ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi  I'm soooo sorry for this, I didn't see it.. You want that i remove my comment ?

Comment: @Superdrac, that's your call. Twice the same information is still better than no information at all :)