# Can you use both the async and defer attributes on a HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I would like to load in the following JavaScript code using both `defer` and `async`:

`<script defer async src="/js/somescript.js"></script>`

Since `defer` is supported by Internet Explorer 5.5+, as you can see at [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=defer), I would like to gracefully fallback to using defer if async is not available. Async I think is better to use when it is available but its not supported until Internet Explorer 10.

My question is therefore is the above code valid HTML? If not, is it possible to create this situation using JavaScript of gracefully falling back to using `defer` on a script when `async` is not available?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68929270/7186739

Answer (score 151, accepted):

From the specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async

> The defer attribute may be specified even if the async attribute is specified, to cause legacy Web browsers that only support defer (and not async) to fall back to the defer behavior instead of the synchronous blocking behavior that is the default.

*(Check the reference link below to see a visual representation of the differences between normal scripts and scripts with defer and async)*

---

References:

- [async vs defer attributes](https://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html)
- [Efficiently load JavaScript with defer and async](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-defer/)

Comment: Is that true?: 1.both `async` `defer` exist, modern browsers run as `async`; 2.both `async` `defer` exist, old browsers run as `defer` instead of `default` behavior

Comment: Don't async and defer do the opposite? Async will load the script simultaneously, but execute when finished loading (pausing the page parsing), but Defer will only execute at the end of all the loading and parsing?

Comment: If the async attribute is present, then the script will be executed asynchronously, as soon as it is available. If the async attribute is not present but the defer attribute is present, then the script is executed when the page has finished parsing. In both cases, page loading isn't blocked.

Comment: @LeoMuller That's why it says "fallback." Modern ones prefer `async` to `defer`. And a yes to @vikyd. If you just don't care about the legacy, you never want to have both on the same `<script>`.

Comment: @dave just making it extra clear:`async` will be downloaded asynchronously, but CAN block DOM parsing (for eg. when served directly from cache). Clarification for " _In both cases, page loading isn't blocked._"

Answer (score 26):

Unfortunately `defer` is ignored when `async` specified, and `async` always have higher priority.

And personally I think that it's very bad that `defer` is ignored by modern browsers (which support `async`). Let's imagine situation when we would like to have some JS initialized ASAP, even before loading of the page content. But we want this script initialized BEFORE the rest of scripts which requires it. It should be first in `defer` queue. But, unfortunately, this will not work:

```
<!-- we want "jQuery" ASAP and still in "defer" queue. But defer is ignored by modern browsers. -->
<script src="jquery.min.js" async defer></script>

<!-- this doesn't blocks the content and can wait the full page load, but requires "jQuery" -->
<script src="some_jquery_plugin.min.js" defer></script>
```

In this sample the "some_jquery_plugin.min.js" can be loaded and executed before the load of jQuery, and will fail. :(

So there is 2 ways to solve the problem: either use only `defer` directive, or merge ALL depending javascript files into single JS to use `async` safely.

Comment: Merging all dependent JS files into a single JS can cause performance issues as the size of bundle can increase and hence the need to breakdown the bundle into chunks again.

Comment: @SachinJain what's wrong if the size of bundle increases?

Comment: @Shad Large JS bundles take more time on the network, and browsers also take more time to parse them. This is why Code Splitting is a technique used to reduce the bundle size.

Comment: how does one decide between size of bundle and the extra HTTP Requests for each that would take place for each individual JS Files?

Comment: @Shad anyway visitor should download all resource files (JS and CSS). Better to have the same or less size (due to gz/brotli compression) and download bundle of JS or CSS in single request.

Answer (score 23):

The question is, what would you expect it to do? 
If both **async** and **defer** are present I would expect the script to be deferred and only executed after DOMContentLoaded when the browser is idle, but if I'm reading the specification right it looks like **defer** is ignored if **async** is set and the script is loaded asynchronously, so will execute as soon as it's available, which may well be before DOMContentLoaded and may block other resources.

> There are three possible modes that can be selected using these attributes. If the async attribute is present, then the script will be executed asynchronously, as soon as it is available. If the async attribute is not present but the defer attribute is present, then the script is executed when the page has finished parsing. If neither attribute is present, then the script is fetched and executed immediately, before the user agent continues parsing the page.

https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async

Answer (score 12):

No.
You need to use `defer` or `async`, but not both. For more see the comparison and use one based on your need.

**defer attribute:** First it will download the script file and then wait of html parsing. After the end of html parsing, script will execute. In other words, It will guarantee all the scripts will execute after the html parsing.

Defer attribute is useful when script is using for DOM manipulations. Means script will apply on document html.

**async attribute:** It will download the script file and execute without wait the end of html parsing. In other words, It will not guarantee all the scripts will execute after the html parsing.

Async attribute is useful when script is not using for DOM manipulation. Some time you need script only for server side operations or for handling cache or cookie but not for DOM manipulations. Means script is not related to the used html.

[image]

Comment: This reply shows up in Google when asking "Can I use async and defer together?". It should start with No, not Yes

Comment: In the current image version, in the top `<script>` part, shouldn't the right green part be significantly longer?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, its valid HTML and it will work like expected.

Any W3C compliant browser will recognize the *async* attribute and treat the script properly, whereas legacy *IE* versions will recognize the *defer* attribute.

Since both attributes are *boolean* you don't *have to* assign any value.

Comment: Thanks @jandy for another great response!

Comment: "... will work like expected." What would you expect it to do though?!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a misconception in most comments here. People don´t seem to know that DEFER also loads the code in parallel, just like ASYNC. But it waits to execute after DOM loads (but before DOMContentLoaded executes), while ASYNC runs it immediately after loading, before DOM loads. Since BOTH ASYNC and DEFER load code in parallel, there would be no need to use both together (but to deal with legacy, maybe).