# Script tag has async & defer at same time

Tags: javascript, html, tags, instagram

There is a schema how it works, when it has each attribute

[image]
but how it would work with both? Both because instagram generates like that for embeds

`<script async defer src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>`

Comment: It does *not* work.

Comment: @Bergi why does facebook generate lake this?

Comment: As the answer to the duplicate says, for "*legacy Web browsers that only support defer (and not async) to fall back*"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68929270/7186739