# What does "async defer" do when used together?

Tags: javascript

I came across the following piece of code:

```
<script src="foo.js" async defer>
```

I understand that `<script async...>` will download the script, then parse it pausing HTML parsing.  I also understand that `<script defer...>` will download the script and parse after all HTML is parsed.

What does `<script async defer...>` do (e.g. async and defer used together)?

Comment: Another explanation of `async` and `defer`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808109/script-tag-async-defer

Comment: Both "async" and "defer" loading external script asynchronously. So you don't need to set them both, unless you really need "async", which has higher priority in modern browsers.

Use "async" if you want to interact your script with page immediately after it will be loaded.
Use "defer" if your script depends on some other script and you should use them in correct order. Eg first is jQuery (defer), following by all jQuery plugins which require jQuery. But never set "async" to jQuery, because it so will be executed in any unpredictable place/time once it will be loaded.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68929270/7186739

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you specify both, `async` takes precedence on modern browsers, while older browsers that support `defer` but not `async` will fallback to `defer`.

For the support table, check `caniuse.com` for [async](https://caniuse.com/#feat=script-async) and for [defer](https://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer).

---

P/s: These attributes make only sense when using the script in the `head` portion of the page, and they are useless if you put the script in the `body` footer.

Comment: So will a modern browser, say Chrome, treat the script as defer or async when it encounters them both?

Comment: `async`. To be clear, `defer` is ignored if `async` is set and the script is loaded asynchronously. If both are present and the browser only supports `defer` then it will fall back to the `defer` behavior.