# Are the html script tag attributes "async" and "defer" mutually exclusive operations?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am working on updating a Google Sign-In component. The Google doc says to include the following in my html file:

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

Here is the doc [Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#implicit-flow).

My understanding of the `async` and `defer` attributes is that they load the script in a different order, and therefor can not both be applied at once. Here is a SO article for reference [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808109/script-tag-async-defer).

So am I misunderstanding something or why is the Google Document telling me to use both tags?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, they're mutually exclusive.

`async` is related to **downloading** of the script. It means that the HTML parsing should not be blocked while downloading the script.

`defer` is related to **execution** of the script. It means that the execution should be *deferred* till all the HTML parsing is completed.

But as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13821238/3930247) noted, if you specify both, `defer` is ignored.

You can still specify both though to support old browsers that don't support `async`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are mutually exclusive. When the `async` attribute is present (and supported), the `defer` one is discarded.

If you look at [the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#prepare-the-script-element), (step 33, [temp link](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#script-processing-model:concept-script-type-12)).

> 33. If *el*'s type is `"classic"` and *el* has a `src` attribute, or *el*'s type is `"module"`:
>
> 1. Assert: *el*'s result is `"uninitialized"`.
>
> 2. If *el* has an `async` attribute or *el*'s force async is true:
>
> 1. Let *scripts* be *el*'s preparation-time document's set of scripts that will execute as soon as possible.
>
> 2. Append *el* to *scripts*.
>
> 3. Set *el*'s steps to run when the result is ready to the following:
>
> 1. Execute the script element *el*.
>
> 2. Remove *el* from *scripts*.
>
> 3. Otherwise, [...]
>     [...]
>   4. Otherwise, if *el* has a `defer` attribute or *el*'s type is `"module"`:

From this we can see that when the `async` attribute is set, the time of the script's execution is already defined, and that the `defer` attribute is discarded through the *Otherwise* logic clause.

You can still let both to fallback on the `defer` behavior when `async` isn't supported though.

Answer (score 0):

defer is ignored when async specified, and async always have higher priority.
but old browsers did not have support for async and it's rather a new option. so when you write

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

it means browser should use async method to load script unless it does not support it, if so it can use defer instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you use both async and defer, then defer will take precedence and the script run when the page load is complete, meaning they are not mutually exclusive.