# How can I properly combine this simple javascript into this tiny php snippet?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, asynchronous

I have a snippet of code in a php (WordPress) page:

```
function vp_contact_popup_add_to_header()
{
// Register the style like this for a plugin:  
wp_register_style( 'videopopup', plugins_url( '/code/css/videopopup.css', __FILE__ ), 
 array(), '20120208', 'all' );
// Register the script like this for a plugin:  
wp_register_script( 'videopopup', plugins_url( '/code/js/videopopup.js', __FILE__ ) );

wp_enqueue_style("videopopup");
wp_enqueue_script("videopopup");
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to add something in there ... like an extra clause to the **javascript portion** of that snippet, like this:

```
<script data-cfasync="false" src="/code/js/videopopup.js"></script>
```

So I want to somehow incorprate the **data-cfasync="false"** into the php snippet, but I'm unsure how to do this.  Any guidance would be truly appreciated!

Comment: The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18945175/1287812) I provided to the `defer` issue should cover this as well, no? . . . : `if ( FALSE !== strpos( $url, 'videopopup.js' ) )`

Comment: Hi Brasofilo.  You code for this issue resulted in the following html output, which seems right to me:  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.occupyhln.org/wp-content/plugins/vimeoyoutubepopup/code/js/videopopup.js' data-cfasync='false'> .... with no semicolon after ... that's just a stackoverflow glitch ... still testing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any way to do this using `wp_register_script()` or `wp_enqueue_script()`. The only way I see to do this (except modifying the header file of the theme) is using the [wp_print_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_scripts) hook directly. You can do it like this:

```
add_action("wp_print_scripts", "addPopupScript");

function addPopupScript() {
    echo '<script data-cfasync="false" src="' . plugins_url( '/code/js/videopopup.js', __FILE__ ) . '"></script>' . "\n";
}
```

But heed the warning in the documentation that this should not be used directly.

Comment: Thank you Gerald.  This resulted in the following html output, which is seemingly perfect:  <script data-cfasync="false" src="http://www.occupyhln.org/wp-content/plugins/vimeoyoutubepopup/code/js/videopopup.js"></script>  ... without the semicolon that stackoverflow throws in there.  I think this will put me on the right track -- still testing.  Thanks for your time!

Comment: This is tested and a proven solution for anybody who has a similar issue.

Comment: This is tested and a proven solution that wants an html output as stated above, however it duplicates a second call to the javascript file; still tinkering with it via the print_scripts hook link Gerald provided to see if I can only get it to call the javascript once.

Comment: Thanks again Gerald ... this solution is tested now.  I hadn't properly eliminated the previous function, and thus was getting a duplicate.  All is perfect now.  BUT ... I'm still trying to figure out where you got the "addPopupScript" from ... or did you just pick a name for the function yourself?

Comment: I just made it up. You have to choose a name that is unique through the WordPress installation (including all plugins and themes that may be installed), so I usually prefix my functions with an abbreviation of the name of my theme/plugin.

Comment: Just a note: If you want to add this to all javascript calls you will be better off with the solution suggested by brasofilo in the comments.