# Adding async attribute

Tags: wordpress, asynchronous, attributes

I'm creating a website using WordPress. So to defer parsing of JavaScript I think I need to add an async attribute. Here I'm calling my scripts using this method.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js',get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
wp_enqueue_script('magnific-popup-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
wp_enqueue_script('wow', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/wow.min.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'parallax', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/jquery.enllax.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'classie', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/classie.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'service', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/service.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'semnox', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/semnox.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'careers-details', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/careers-details.js', false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'event', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/jquery.event.move.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'twenty', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/jquery.twentytwenty.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'global', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/script.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'infosys', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/infosys.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true ); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'careers', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/careers.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true ); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'video', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/video.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'monest', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/monest.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'prajavani', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/prajavani.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wow', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/wow.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
wp_enqueue_script('owl-carousel', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/owl.carousel.min.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'script2', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/script2.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
```

Comment: Check this thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944027/how-do-i-defer-or-async-this-wordpress-javascript-snippet-to-load-lastly-for-fas

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Add this code in functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'async_filter', 10, 2 );

function async_filter( $tag, $handle ) {
    if($handle =="global"){
    return str_replace( ' src', ' async src', $tag );           
    }else{
    return $tag;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187151/discussion-on-answer-by-vel-adding-async-attribute).