# HTML5 script tags, does defer wait on any previous async scripts

Tags: javascript, html

The HTML5 script tag loading directives seem pretty cool https://stackoverflow.com/a/24070373/1070291

Is it possible to async load a bunch of scripts but have a single script wait to execute based on the async ones completing.

```
<script src="//some.cdn/jquery.js" async></script>
<script src="//some.cdn/underscore.js" async></script>
<script src="/my-app-which-uses-_-and-jquery.js" defer></script>
```

Is my app script guaranteed to execute after my libraries or will it only execute in order with other defer scripts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Script Tag - async & defer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808109/script-tag-async-defer)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I think this is a different question, the one linked is more about the general behaviour of async/defer this question is about the interactions between the two when used togeather

Comment: Maybe, but it has your answer.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara really? I cant see it in there. jfriend00 talks about not using all async but not about if async and defer interact

Comment: Oh, I think I see. You are asking if `defer` will wait for `async`?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara yup :) the answer happens to be no, but I don't think that was the intent of what jfriend00 was saying

Comment: In that case, vote retracted! I think you could make them all `defer`, does that not work for you?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara yeah I think that's the best way, I was just hoping to squeeze a little more juice out by loading the libraries in any order (conciser the case where the first is really big, the second could execute while the first is still downloading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `defer` present, it specifies that the script is executed when the page has finished parsing. It doesn't include `async` scripts.

If I have the following situation which all scripts will log the date when it was executed:

```
   <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
       <script src="script.js" async></script>
       <script src="script2.js" async></script>
       <script src="script3.js" defer></script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <script>
        console.log("Body script executed at : " + new Date());
     </script>
   </body>
```

I may have this output:

```
  Body script executed at : Tue Feb 17 2015 00:05:08 GMT-0300
  script2.js:2 Script 2 executed at :Tue Feb 17 2015 00:05:08 GMT-0300
  script.js:2 Script 1 executed at:Tue Feb 17 2015 00:05:08 GMT-0300
  script3.js:2 Script 3 executed at :Tue Feb 17 2015 00:05:08 GMT-0300
```

`script3.js (defer)` will wait for '`<body>`', but not for `script1.js (async)`, `script2.js(async)`.

Here is a [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/O0GXLLm82w12xNflNZJW?p=info)

Comment: I think 'script3.js (defer) will wait for script1.js (async), script2.js(async) and '' in order to be executed.' is incorrect, I get 3 happening in the middle of the other 2 when I try your sample

Comment: defer will wait for <body>, not for async scripts. I will just update my answer

Comment: The answer seems to be no, thats a bit of a shame really.

Comment: Looks like It's a good idea mark as async only the script who nobody depends on it to be executed.