# What's the difference between document.ready and async?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, document-ready

Script in `async` is loaded after the page loads and `(document).ready` execute the script on DOM ready, but what is the difference? And which one makes the page loads faster?

```
<script>   
  $(document).ready(function(){
    //some code
  }); 
</script>
```

VS

```
<script async>   
    //some code
</script>
```

Comment: You can refer to this answer "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934845/whats-the-difference-between-document-ready-and-just-omit-it". You can get a clear idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For

```
<script async>   
    //some code
</script>
```

the `async` attribute will be ignored, because `async` is [only meaningful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes) when a `<script>` has a `src` attribute:

> This attribute must not be used if the src attribute is absent (i.e. for inline scripts). If it is included in this case it will have no effect.

So, the `<script async>` in your question will block HTML parsing once the tag is encountered - it won't operate asynchronously at all.

If the script tag *did* have a `src`, then the `async` tag will download the script asynchronously (HTML parsing is not blocked), and then execute the script as soon as the script has been downloaded (whether or not the page has finished loading first). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808109/script-tag-async-defer)

`$(document).ready(function(){` requires the `DOMContentLoaded` event to fire before the containing function runs, and `DOMContentLoaded` will run only once the HTML has been completely parsed (though not necessarily before all *resources* have been downloaded, like images and such).

So, the `async` script with a `src` tag may execute sooner than `$(document).ready(function(){`.

Do note that there's a `defer` tag, which is *nearly the same* as `$(document).ready(function(){` - a script with a `defer` tag (and a `src`) will run *just before* the `DOMContentLoaded` event fires.

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN, [async has no effect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes) for inline script tag, so the fact that worked probably means the script happens to be at the bottom of the html.

document.ready is a deprecated way jQuery lets you make a DOMContentLoaded listener, and it is better to do `jQuery(function($) {...}` and include code in that.