# When can we use async?

Tags: javascript

Async script loading is what i'm learning now. I have a question about `async` attr in script tag - `<script async src="...">`.

here is some info, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp and my question is about this - **When present, it specifies that the script will be executed asynchronously as soon as it is available.** line.

Question:
If i have 2 scripts:

```
<script async src="url1.js"><script> // 200kb
<script async src="url2.js"><script> // 2kb
```

and the second `script` must be executed AFTER first (it uses some `Objects` or `functions` from it) - will it be so after page load? will first script execute first after loading, and then - the second, or not?

From bold string above - I understand it so, that than faster the `script` was loaded - the faster it will be executed, and in our example we will have errors, while first `script` wasn't loaded and executed yet, but second is already trying to get it. (and when we can use `async` script loading? only when our scripts are not independent of each other?)

p.s. is `lazy loading script` the only way to get the correct script execution order in this case - to prevent errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the `async` attribute, the browser will stop processing the page and first download the referenced script; once the script is downloaded and executed it will continue processing the next tag on the page. This has two consequences:

1. All scripts are guaranteed to load in the order they're included in the HTML, and dependencies are guaranteed to resolve correctly.
2. The page loading is noticeably delayed, if those scripts are included early. Synchronous scripts should always be included at the end of the page to not leave the visitor waiting needlessly.

If you set the `async` attribute, the browser will continue loading the page without stopping to process the `script` tag, and will load the script *sometime later*. When exactly the script is loaded is undefined and you cannot depend on any particular order of execution. If you have dependencies between two scripts, you cannot load them `async`hronously, because then it's down to pure luck whether one will load before the other.

As such, `async` loading is only useful for scripts which have no other dependencies. ***Or:*** you hook your scripts to the `window.onload` event and avoid making any cross references before then; the event will be fired after all scripts have loaded, including `async` scripts.

Comment: and if i will call **first** script `functions` after `window.onload` event from the second? will they work? (with another words: `load` event fires after all `async scripts` loading? and what about `DOMContentLoaded` event?)

Comment: Yes, if you hook your scripts to `window.onload` and avoid any cross-references until `window.onload` has fired, you're also guaranteed to have resolved all dependencies. That's a useful pattern as well.

Answer (score 3):

**If url2.js depends on url1.js you cannot use async loading for script files you must use synchronous** (eager loading) to ensure that url1.js is loaded and executed before url2.js.

Using async two cases can occur:

1. url1.js loads and executes then url2.js loads and executes. This is okay as url1 will be ready for url2.
2. url2.js loads and executes then url1.js loads and executes. This will fail as url2 depends on url1 which is not ready at the time url2 is.

Using non-async loading only one case can occur, which is url1.js loading and executing before url2.js loads and executes which is what you need if they depend on each other.

In async loading you can't control when they are executed, they execute as soon as they are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar Question asked earlier.

[Script Tag - async & defer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808109/script-tag-async-defer)

And about the order of execution, JavaScript execution happens in the order they're placed in HTML. If your page relies on the JavaScript for certain events and if the JS Methods are loaded before your Page, then they'll result in the JS Error.

I would suggest you to use the CallBack functions where possible to avoid the above errors. [Here](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) is a good place to start to learn about the CallBack functions and how you can implement them.