# Practically using script async or defer with frameworks like angular

Tags: javascript, html, script-tag

Have been studying the use of `async` and `defer` in script tags. Given the following...

> async - Allows the rest of the html to parse, while the JS script is being loaded. Once the script is completely loaded then the html
>   parser is paused to execute the script. However, note that the order
>   of loading can't be controlled.
>
> defer - Also allows the rest of the html to parse, however the loaded
>   js is only executed once the html parsing is complete.
>
> So, if you can afford to show your html without loading your js script
>   first... use `async`. If more than one script is involved and
>   the order they are loaded matters then use `defer`. On the other hand, if your scripts MUST be loaded first (and can't be rewritten to allow the
>   html to parse first) then just load the script without using `async` or
>   `defer` in the header.

How would this fit with modern frameworks like AngularJS... since, delaying their loading results in an error. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Script Tag - async & defer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808109/script-tag-async-defer)

Comment: Have changed the question above. Please provide feedback.

Comment: Angular just has to be loaded before your custom scripts otherwise you get errors since angular isn't defined yet so asynchronous would not be a good idea. Defer would work though. Another option that might be simpler then using defer is simply put your script tags at the bottom of your html body element so they are loaded after the html.

Comment: Uhh... how would defer work!? I thought Angular is required beforehand, so wouldn't using defer (or end of body inclusion) defeat the purpose?

Comment: @Grateful defer will load scripts in order. Manual bootstraping angular will solve this, but not if lazy loadind controllers/providers, which I do a lot..

Answer (score 0):

Considering that an Angular app depends entirely on the Angular JS files and dependencies, it doesn't make much sense to defer or async them unless you have a fallback (like a loading state, perhaps?). With that said, however, adding defer to all of the scripts would likely work fine, but not do much in terms of performance. Adding async could break things since certain dependencies are required to load before others.