# How do I run a jQuery function after jQuery is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At my website, I am loading jQuery asynchronously.

In order to do that, I must run jQuery functions only after it is really loaded.

I've tried two pure JS ways:

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.2.2.min.js" async></script>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        //stuff
    }, true);
</script>
```

And

```
window.onload = function() {
    //stuff
}
```

But even so I still get `Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is not a function at...`

How do I fire jQuery functions after the lib is fully loaded?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You just need to add code after jquery library loaded (script tag)

Comment: You get that error when jQuery **isn't** loaded at all. Load jQuery first, then as @PranavCBalan suggested add the rest afterwards.. Plus if you just wrap the functions in `$(document).ready(` you should 90% of the time be ok.

Comment: Yes. I cannot just put after the lib because I am loading the lib asynchronously in order to suit Google PageSpeed Insights requirements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if jquery is loaded using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341865/checking-if-jquery-is-loaded-using-javascript)

Comment: Inject scripts like Google does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make script execution wait until jquery is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486309/how-to-make-script-execution-wait-until-jquery-is-loaded)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add the script only after jQuery library is loaded using script tag.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // your code should be here
  alert(typeof jQuery)
</script>
```

---

The [document ready handler](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) is using to execute the code only after DOM elements are loaded.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  console.log('Outside document ready handler ' + $('.test').length)

  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('Inside document ready handler ' + $('.test').length)
  });
</script>
<div class="test"></div>
```

---

**UPDATE 1:** You can use `defer` if script is in a file, refer following question: [jquery loaded async and ready function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272020/jquery-loaded-async-and-ready-function-not-working)

---

**UPDATE 2:** Or you can bind [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) event handler to the script tag using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method.

```html
<script async id="script" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('script')
    .addEventListener('load', function() {
      alert(typeof jQuery)
    });
</script>
```

**FYI :** I don't know why you are doing this, for optimizing the speed of content load it's always better to move the script tags at the end of `body` which helps to load content first.

Comment: Thanks. But as described in the question, I must load jQuery asynchronously.

Comment: Sure. Edited the post.

Comment: @Luiz : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272020/jquery-loaded-async-and-ready-function-not-working

Comment: Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: In your second example you're using jquery to check for jquery. If '$' is not loaded, you aren't going to be able to run $(document).ready()

Comment: The "bind" solution was perfect for my usage case - running a piece of script from console to inject jQuery into a page, and then run jQuery-specific functions (once they were available). Thank you for the solution, @PranavCBalan

Answer (score 9):

You could do something like this:

```
function checkVariable(){
   if ( window.jQuery){
      Do your jquery stuff here
   }
   else{
      window.setTimeout("checkVariable();",100);
   }
}
checkVariable();
```

Apologies for the formatting...stuck on my phone right now.

Comment: You need to change `windows.setTimeout` to `window.setTimeout`

Comment: This worked perfectly in a particular project where I was only allowed to insert html, css, and javascript in the middle of the body (through PHP), but was not allowed to add more custom javascript at the end of the body, where jQuery and other js scripts were loaded.

Answer (score 3):

I did not see this method listed, so I thought I would demonstrate using the [JavaScript HTML DOM EventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp).

**Example #1 Using the [jQuery.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) Method:**

```html
<p id="test-jquery">jQuery Not Loaded</p>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var elem = $('#test-jquery');
    elem.text('jQuery Is Loaded');
  });
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This method will not work since [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) has yet to be loaded.
Running the above example will output:

```
ERROR: {
  "message": "ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 13,
  "colno": 3
}
```

**Example #2 Using the [addEventListener()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) Method:**

```html
<p id="test-jquery">jQuery Not Loaded</p>

<script>
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elem = $('#test-jquery');
    elem.text('jQuery Is Loaded');
  });
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This method will work since we are listening for the [Window DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event).

From [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/):

> The original target for this event is the [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) that has loaded.
> You can listen for this event on the Window interface to handle it in
> the capture or bubbling phases. For full details on this event please
> see the page on the Document: [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) event.
>
> A different event, [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event), should be used only to detect a fully-loaded
> page. It is a common mistake to use load where DOMContentLoaded would
> be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => {
        if (event.target.readyState === "complete") {
            // window loaded, external resources are loaded too...
            jQuery(function($) {
                // your code here: $("a").css(...)
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

I used it when inline jQuery script did not work on safari (Mac and iOS) and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.ready` or load the library in the header. That should work.. Be sure to load in the right folder or in the right link. If you are usying a link to load jquery then be sure to have an internet connection

Comment: When loading the library synchronously all happens ok. The problem is that I must load it with `async` parameter.

Comment: As described in the question, yes.

Comment: If you want that async that will be async.. You can try to look for jQl here: http://www.yterium.net/jQl-an-asynchronous-jQuery-Loader