# what browser rendering stage is blocking js and css loaded?

Tags: html, performance, google-chrome, firefox

I've been looking at this site: https://varvy.com/performance/ and am confused on where blocking css / JS loads are measured.  Is it between `domLoading` & `domInteractive` or between `responseEnd` and `domLoading`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got a little clarification, and the answer is... "It depends".  Looking at http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html

If you use a plain `script` tag, it will block inline during the parsing of the html.

If you use `DEFER`, the blocking bit will always happen after the HTML is finished rendering.

If you use `ASYNC`, the blocking bit can happen at any time (during the HTML rendering, or after depending on how long it takes to download), but BEFORE

ALSO: reference [Script Tag - async & defer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808109/script-tag-async-defer)

So unfortunately there is no easy answer.