# add async and differ in the script with value false

Tags: javascript

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

I want to add async and differ in the following script . This is the code for the google map that showing more resource consuption. I want to make this code more responsive by adding async and differ

Comment: What makes you think that the Google Maps library is the source of your performance problems? Could you add a little more detail on what exactly your issue is? Modifying Google's code is probably not the right solution - I get the feeling this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: when I checked google developer speed test I found an error my page has one blocking resource.Advised to remove render blocking java script as this script. I think after adding async and defer to this script we can resolve this issue

Comment: Ah, I see - I was getting slightly mixed up with the `async` keyword in JavaScript, sorry!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Script Tag - async & defer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808109/script-tag-async-defer) - hopefully the answers to this question will help you out.

Comment: I checked ... Can anyone suggest how can I modify the text?