# Add script tags and load scripts sequentially

Tags: javascript

I have the following function that loads a given script :

```
function addScriptTag(url){
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = url;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

I used the function to load libs correlated to each other where `lib2` depends on `lib1` and `lib1` depends on `jquery` :

```
function loadThemAll(){
  addScriptTag('http://path/to/jquery.js');
  addScriptTag('http://path/to/lib1.js');
  addScriptTag('http://path/to/lib2.js');
}
```

The problem is that even in that order, when `lib1` needs jQuery, it doesn't find it. The same applies for `lib2` that uses `lib1`.

How can I make script tag creates **and** load the script sequentially ?
In other words :

add script tag for `jQuery` and load it.

When `jQuery` is loaded, add script tag for `lib1` and load it.

When `lib1` is loaded, add script tag for `lib2` and load it.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't waiting for the previous script to load before attempting to load the next one, you could try using `Promises` and the `onload` callback of the script elements.

```js
function addScriptTag(url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.onload = resolve;
    script.onerror = reject;
    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  })
}

addScriptTag('http://path/to/jquery.js').then(function() {
  return addScriptTag('http://path/to/lib1.js');
}).then(function() {
  return addScriptTag('http://path/to/lib2.js');
});
```

Since the `onload` method of the new script is set to the resolve of the returned `Promise` of `addScriptTag` this should cause the scripts to wait until the previous one was loaded.

You could take it a step further and write a function that takes a list of scripts to load sequentially:

```js
function loadScripts(scripts, promise) {
  if (!promise) {
    promise = new Promise();
  }

  script = scripts.shift();
  if (script) {
    addScriptTag(script).then(function () {
      loadScripts(scripts, promise);
    }).catch(function () {
      promise.reject();
    });
  } else {
    promise.resolve();
  }

  return promise;
}

loadScripts([
  'http://path/to/jquery.js',
  'http://path/to/lib1.js', 
  'http://path/to/lib2.js'
]).then(function () {
  console.log("Scripts loaded");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have `addScriptTag` return a Promise that resolves when the script is loaded, and `await` each call:

```
function addScriptTag(url){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.addEventListener('load', resolve);
    script.addEventListener('error', reject);
    script.src = url;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  });
}


async function loadThemAll(){
  await addScriptTag('http://path/to/jquery.js');
  await addScriptTag('http://path/to/lib1.js');
  await addScriptTag('http://path/to/lib2.js');
}

loadThemAll()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Everything is loaded!');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('There was a problem:', err);
  });
```

You can also use `async=false`, but this will *block* until the script loads, so may not be a great idea:

```
function addScriptTag(url){
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('async', 'false');
  script.src = url;
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}


function loadThemAll(){
  addScriptTag('http://path/to/jquery.js');
  addScriptTag('http://path/to/lib1.js');
  addScriptTag('http://path/to/lib2.js');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can add `defer` attribute to your scripts. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808109/script-tag-async-defer) for more details

Comment: Oh yes, I found more info on that. It appears that `defer` only works on script tags initially parsed by browser and is ignored on dynamically added scripts.