# How to wait until functions to be loaded inside script src tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addeventlistener

I am trying to load one of the js file using **script src**, but functions(methods) inside this src file will always take time to load. (Note: script tag's src= "emscripten_model.js" is generated with help of emscripten ).

I tried to use below function and callback , but callback function gets called even methods inside src are not loaded yet.

```
 this.loadModel = function(path,onloadCallback) {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('async', '');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.addEventListener('load', () => {
        console.log("now ready to call callback!!!");
      onloadCallback();

    });
    script.addEventListener('error', () => {
        self.printError('Failed to load ' + path);
    });
    script.src = path;
    let node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(script, node);
    console.log("ccccccccccccc");
};
```

I tried **settimeout** or **setinterval** to avoid the above issue, But Is there any way I can handle without **settimeout** or **setinterval** .

Is there anyway I can handle better using callback or addeventlistener, please provide me piece of code to solve this.

Comment: Looks like you need a module loader. If only there was a way of [asynchronously importing modules natively](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) in modern browsers...

Comment: @BlueWater86 , thanks for guidance. In My case I have a emscrippten js codes enclosed in a function called:  function module_calculation{ /*js code is here*/} and exported this as : var Module_CalAlign = module_calculation();. I written in plain jaavscript function , Is there anyway I can handle to wait until this module_calculation() function loads.

Answer (score 1):

this is not an answer but i believe this will help you.

if jquery its gong to be $(document).ready(function(){});
if pure javascript refer to link below:

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t)

Comment: This not the right one. In My case I have a emscrippten js codes enclosed in a function called:  function module_calculation{ /*js code is here*/} and exported this as : var Module_CalAlign = module_calculation();. I written in plain jaavscript function , Is there anyway I can handle to wait until this module_calculation() function loads.

Comment: can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808109/script-tag-async-defer see if it can help you