# Include splitted code of react vendor.js chunk in main bundle.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack

This question is regarding code splitting in react, Let us take an example where I have my bundle.js file

I split it into two files `bundle.js` and `vendor.js`, and I can include this in my `index.html`

```
index.html
  <script src='./bundle.js'/>
  <script src='./vendor.js'/>
```

Is there a way so that I can include `vendor.js` file in my `bundle.js` file and both file then can be loaded parallel.

Comment: looks like this question is what need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808109/script-tag-async-defer

Comment: Typically, Webpack would generate an `index.html` for you with the script injected. Can you include your Webpack config?

Answer (score 2):

well.. if you are using webpack as your module bundler, then following piece of code is responsible for code splitting.. Just remove the code responsible for splitting into chunks.

```
optimization: {
//        splitChunks: {
//          cacheGroups: {
//            commons: {
//              test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
//              name: "vendors",
//              chunks: "all"
//            }
//          }
//        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack, it does this automatically for you (If you use [dynamic](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) import or set [chunks](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#splitchunksplugin)).

But if want to do this manually, you could create a [script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) element in `bundle.js`. And set async or defer based on your use case.