# How are external scripts/modules within a DOM loaded?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/chessboard-1.0.0.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="js/gitchess/chess.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/chessboard-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="js/frontend.js"></script>
    <title>CHESS</title>
</head>
```

Since objects inside chess.js aren't accessible unless they are `import` 'ed, are they loaded into a separate file? For that matter, how are module scripts loaded into DOM as opposed to regular scripts?

Comment: Not being accessible (in the global scope) doesn't mean that they are not loaded or that the module code would not be executed. It is, just like the other scripts are.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean how scripts are loaded behind the scenes there are 3 ways that I put this image which explains ideally based on the different script loadings:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULvu1.png

As you can see, the script that has 'defer' is parsed simultaneously but will be executed after the HTML is parsed completely. The order in which you write the scripts becomes essential if you need some data to be available sooner.

```
<script type="module" src="js/gitchess/chess.js" defer></script>
```

The async attribute, by the way, pauses the HTML parsing process and starts executing the script files. The order is not essential though.

```
<script type="module" src="js/gitchess/chess.js" async></script>
```

I hope I have understood your question as it should.
By the way, the complete explanation is provided by other developers [Script Tag - async & defer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808109/script-tag-async-defer) and the information given above is just a short and easy one.

Comment: Did you draw this image yourself? If not, please cite your source.

Comment: Of course not, just google js script loading attributes (async - defer) it brings different ones and this one was the easiest to explain in my opinion

Comment: Then you'll need to [reference the source properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). Please [edit] your answer or it will likely get deleted.

Comment: I edited and added the complete explanation link for you.