# Nextjs optimization for mobile

Tags: javascript, node.js, cdn

Hello all I am facing performance issue for mobile can anyone suggest how to improve these following points
[image: These are the following issues I am facing]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways:-

1st Find out Which JS is taking more time to load, you can optimize that by using the NextJs Script tag link - [Nextjs Script](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script)

2nd If nextjs/Script does not work in your case then as the Page Speed index is showing your 3rd Party Scripts take more time to load, Please reduce them if they don't need or call them in the footer by using async. - [Call Script faster using async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808109/script-tag-async-defer)

3rd Avoid writing the whole website's CSS into global CSS. Make abcd.module.css of your particular page, so that you can call only the CSS which is used on that page. [Built-In CSS Support](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support)