# Why does my carousel rotate when the page loads, but then stops completely?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a full-stack application and for my hero page, I am working on adding a carousel that rotates images in the background.

So far I have created the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files.

When the page loads, it rotates but then the carousel stops working and just stays on the first line.

I am not too sure if there is an error in my code but I would appreciate it if someone helped me out.

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
var currentSlide = 0;

function changeSlide() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
  }

  currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % slides.length;
  slides[currentSlide].style.opacity = 1;
}

setInterval(changeSlide, 3000);
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}
/*------------------------------Hero Page---------------------------------*/
.carousel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  .slide:first-child {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .slide-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
  }
  .slide-1 {
    background-image: url(Images/derek-baumgartner-A7sfB4yKS7s-unsplash.jpg);
  }
  
  .slide-2 {
    background-image: url(Images/andrew-bain-jO_Q3EY_T0E-unsplash.jpg);
  }
  
  .slide-3 {
    background-image: url(Images/aaron-dowd-N7PDwky8doM-unsplash.jpg);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <script src="practice.js"></script>
     <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="practice.css">
    <title>Welcome to Washington State - Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <!------------Hero Page-------------->
    <header>
        <div class="carousel">
            <div class="slide slide-1">
              <div class="slide-content">Slide 1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide slide-2">
              <div class="slide-content">Slide 2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide slide-3">
              <div class="slide-content">Slide 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are loading your script before the page has been created and the script is running as soon as it is loaded.

You can add `defer` to the script, like so:

`<script src="practice.js" defer></script>`

Or you can move the script to the end of the HTML.

[Script Tag - async & defer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808109/script-tag-async-defer) would be a good source of information to read for this problem.

To make it easier to see your problem, I removed your images and simply set a `background-color`, `height`, and `width` in the CSS to see the slides and I reduced the delay in `setInterval` to 1500.

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
var currentSlide = 0;

function changeSlide() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
  }

  currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % slides.length;
  slides[currentSlide].style.opacity = 1;
}

setInterval(changeSlide, 1500);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
}


/*------------------------------Hero Page---------------------------------*/

.carousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.slide:first-child {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slide-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.slide-1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
}

.slide-2 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
}

.slide-3 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="practice.js" defer></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="practice.css">
  <title>Welcome to Washington State - Home Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!------------Hero Page-------------->
  <header>
    <div class="carousel">
      <div class="slide slide-1">
        <div class="slide-content">Slide 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide-2">
        <div class="slide-content">Slide 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide-3">
        <div class="slide-content">Slide 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```