# initMap is not a function using Google Maps Javascript API in Next.js component

Tags: google-maps, next.js

I have a `Next.js` page which shows a Map component using the Advanced Markers functionality documented [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/start). I'm intermittently getting the following error when the page loads:
**InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function**

If the user navigates away from the page and then returns, there's no error.

Because of the Advanced Markers functionality the script can't be imported as a package, so instead I'm using the `Next.js` `Script` tag. I use a useEffect to check that we have a `window`, and I'm also using setInterval to delay running the `initMap` code until (in theory) the script is loaded.

```
useEffect(() => {
   function initMap() {
       const interval = setInterval(() => {
  if (
    typeof window !== "undefined" &&
    window.google &&
    window.google.maps
  ) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    if (googlemap.current) {
      const map = new google.maps.Map(googlemap.current, {
        center: { lat: coords[0]?.lat, lng: coords[0]?.lng },
        zoom: 15,
        mapId: "d2a1a27e40cc216a",
      });

      const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

      for (const coord of coords) {
        const advancedMarkerView =
          new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerView({
            map,
            content: buildContent(coord),
            position: { lat: coord?.lat, lng: coord?.lng },
            zIndex: 1,
          });
        const element = advancedMarkerView.element;
        bounds.extend(advancedMarkerView.position);
      }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  }
}, 1000);
}
initMap();
}, []);
return (
    <>
        <Script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&v=beta&libraries=marker&callback=initMap' />
        <div ref={googlemap} className='h-full w-full'></div>
    </>
)
```

Can anyone see what I' doing wrong? What's the correct, rock-solid way of implementing a Google map in `Next.js` using the Javascript API and Advanced Markers functionality, please?

Comment: Good username :) Try defining your `initMap` function as a window object property. Something like `window.initMap = initMap;`. There are a number of related questions here. Please check.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Cheers! That seems to have worked. Will happily mark that as correct if you add it as an answer. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview), loading the API should be done this way:

> *The `defer` attribute causes the callback to execute after the full HTML document has been parsed. For non-blocking uses, avoiding race conditions, and consistent behavior across browsers, consider loading using Promises with https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader.*

Loading the script without the `defer` (or `async`) attribute often leads to an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) - initMap is not a function
```

```js
function initMap() {
  // Do nothing
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Adding `defer` (or `async`) to the HTML script tag gets rid of this error.

```js
function initMap() {
  // Do nothing
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Other ways and instructions on how to load the API can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview#Loading_the_Maps_API).

Most code examples in the documentation also mention that you should attach the callback function to the `window` object:

```
// Attach your callback function to the `window` object
window.initMap = function() {
  // JS API is loaded and available
};
```

Or an equivalent:

```
function initMap() {
  // Your code here
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

Using `asnyc` / `defer` attributes is your own choice and will often depend on how your website / app is configured and loads the various scripts and/or APIs you will need. To understand the main differences, you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808109/script-tag-async-defer).