# How to prevent the page from loading until a script in the head with promises resolve

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have an external *asynchronous* script needs to finish executing before the page loads. To my understanding (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808109/script-tag-async-defer) thread), the default behaviour before the page starts to load is that it finishes rendering the head tag's contents, and if it includes a script, it finishes parsing that too, *before* proceeding to load the page. However, I could be wrong, but this seems to not apply to asynchronous scripts.

How could I make this example asynchronous script below finish executing (and all promises finishing) *before* the page *starts* to load?

The page, including the script:

Playground: https://playcode.io/1782092

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>p {color: blue}</style>

    <script>
  // Function to create a fake promise that resolves after 3 seconds
  async function fakePromise() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(resolve, 3000); // Resolve after 3 seconds
    });
  }

  // Use async/await to wait for the fake promise to resolve
  async function applyStyle() {
    await fakePromise();

    // Create a <style> element
    var styleElement = document.createElement('style');

    // Define the CSS rule
    var css = "p { color: pink !important; }";

    // Add the CSS rule to the <style> element
    styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));

    // Insert the <style> element into the <head> of the document
    document.head.insertBefore(styleElement, document.head.firstChild);
  }

  // Call the function to apply the style
  applyStyle();

  // *** in the REAL app, this script would just have empty contents and have a src attribute ***
</script>

  </head>
  <body>
    
    <p>testing</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the example 'testing' text changes colour after 3 seconds, but the problem is that this happens after the page has loaded. The blue 'testing' text should never appear, because the promise wouldn't have resolved by then, and when it is resolved, it changes to pink, hence you should only see pink text.

If this is not possible, how else could I, for example, redirect to another page after the asynchronous script finishes but before the page starts to load?

Comment: Your playcode doesn't work - and looks unrelated to the code in the question

Comment: You can create a function in js .. run this then that, and set your functions according to that, I have posted a redirect code at the end of header and increased the settime value to 6000

Comment: This code is related to the question, because it shows that the 'testing' paragraph element renders before the promise resolves, which is wrong

Comment: What is the point? With this approach you only make the user wait for 3 seconds. Whether they see color change after 3 seconds or a loading screen for 3 seconds... you'll make them wait.

Comment: The real app is for an AB test where there are either (1) injected CSS styles, or (2) a page redirect. I don't want to show different varying styles and then more changed styles after loading as this would appear snappy on load. The page must not load until any promises complete

Comment: Is this really about loading CSS?

Comment: It’s mainly just about preventing the page from loading until any promises resolve. Window.stop() prevents the load but I don’t think you can tell it to continue without refreshing the page

Comment: It seems like fundamentally you are trying to make the asynchronous script behave synchronously, which would be trivial to do by removing any `async` tag. Can you give any more details about why the script is necessarily asynchronous? Would it be sufficient to fake that the page is not loaded, by (say) hiding all of its contents through CSS until the script completes?

Comment: Sure -the script must be async because an API will need to be called to determine whether to add CSS, JS or redirect the user. The AB tests have different variants which could be injecting CSS and/or JS, or redirecting the user to another page - when someone visits the page, there is a script in the head that calls an API to determine which variant to show, and the problem is that the page continues to load before the result of the API, so it often partially loads the page and their either redirects or displays CSS. I want to know if there's a better alternative to displaying a loading spinner

Comment: There must be pages elsewhere on the web that need to check an API before redirecting or adding CSS/JS - I would be curious to know what they do on page load, whether they display 'loading', for example

Comment: "*there is a script in the head that calls an API to determine which variant to show*" - this is a bad idea. It should be your web server that calls this API, and then serves either the page with the css or a different page with different css or the redirect or whatever.

Comment: …or if you cannot put the decision code in the web server that serves the html page, you can still put it in the web server that serves the stylesheet or script that is loaded from the html.

Comment: This is an AB testing platform that enables any website owner to create an account and create their own AB tests for their own website. I won’t have access to their server or code - the only way I can think of doing it is by getting them to add a script in the head of their web pages and let the script do the job - just like how you install google analytics. Are you suggesting there may be a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you block the page from loading, you are forcing your end users to wait without feedback: you won't be able to show a loading spinner or anything else, and the user will perceive the delay as a frozen page or slow server. This is why a lot of attention is spent on minimizing the [critical rendering path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Critical_rendering_path), which Google (at least) uses as some of the [Core Web Vitals](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/core-web-vitals), which are [reportedly included in page ranking signals](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/page-experience)*.

Generally speaking, the good move is to transition synchronous resources to asychronous resources, allowing your page to render as soon as possible even if the content it loads appears shortly thereafter. Though this won't necessarily help with "contentful paints" in Core Web Vitals, it will provide a more positive user experience.

If you need to run an A/B test, you might find it more effective to deliver the A/B test status as a server-side calculation, or to stay with your loading spinner behavior and try to optimize or cache the API calculation as much as possible.

---

*Disclaimer: I am a Google employee, but do not and have not worked on page ranking algorithms. I am speaking only for myself based only on publicly available documentation.

Comment: Very useful response, thank you. I overlooked the UX impact. Given that the script will be placed on multiple client websites that I do not control (hence why the script needs to do everything - I can't directly edit their page but the script can), would I be correct in assuming that the best solution is to display a loading spinner while the API is fetching (i.e. as an overlay, by the script inserting HTML and CSS and adding a class to the body or something), and then just remove the overlay when the API has responded?

Comment: @user8758206 I don't know enough about your use case and requirements to be able to meaningfully assert that it's the _best_ solution, especially because a nontrivial content-blocking API call is going to have page performance effects on your clients' sites, but based on your post I can tell you that I am much more optimistic an async+spinner solution than I am about trying to halt loading or rendering. With async you could set a useful timeout, log API performance, cache results to avoid the API call entirely, and lots of other useful solutions to minimize latency and improve the UX.

Answer (score 1):

Your question kind of blows my mind...

The usual problem is the reverse: Ensuring all HTML (or at least the part we want to work with) is rendered before running javascript (to ensure we find in place the DOM nodes we want to work with...).

As far as I could understand you are trying to set some CSS rules and don't want **to see** the document rendered until that rules are defined (in this case, until the CSS makes the text to be pink instead of blue) **and**, for some reason, that style cannot be decided until some asynchronous event happen (network request to some API I guess...).

If the only problem is that you don't want to see the document contents before that even happening, you can just hide it either with `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` and then revert it when the awaited event (your promise resolution) finally happen.

*Technically* `display: none` is "almost" what you're asking for, because no element is actually rendered (it's not just you don't see them). ...**BUT** I'd rather advice you to opt for `visibility: hidden` because, this way, HTML is actually rendered (despite you don't see it) and when you finally switch *visibility* to "visible" your page will show up instantly while, with the *display* approach, it would start to render at that moment.

To sum up, if `p` is your promise, it would look like something like this:

```js
document.body.style.visibility="hidden";
/* ... */
p.then(()=>document.body.style.visibility="visible";
```

Comment: Good points. Would inserting a loading spinner overlay that goes over everything make adding visibility hidden or display none unnecessary?

Comment: also, I am not sure whether your code would work, because the script must be in the head, and the body tag has not yet been parsed, meaning you may get an error like `Cannot read property body of null` or something. Also adding it in a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener won't work either, since it would only apply it after the body has completely loaded

Comment: (1) Of course a spinner will provide better UX than blank page (I just tried to stickt to your requirements. Visibility:hidden could be avoidable if your spinner have a solid background and covers the whole window/document.

(2) Good point: You're right, sorry (I just tried to illustrate the concept and I missed that point. But there are lots of simple solutions, like putting that css directly in the tag `<body style="visibility:hidden">`. BTW technically you may need to ensure that your promise could not resolve before the body being rendered (or add some workaround code for that case...)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will be helpful for your purpose. But, here you go.

So, I have set the `body` `display` to `none` till the `fakePromise()` resolves. Once the promise resolves, the body is displayed with all the changes incorporated.

https://playcode.io/1784955

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>p {color: blue}</style>

    <script>
  // Function to create a fake promise that resolves after 3 seconds
  async function fakePromise() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(resolve, 3000); // Resolve after 3 seconds
    });
  }

  // Use async/await to wait for the fake promise to resolve
  async function applyStyle() {
    await fakePromise();

    // Create a <style> element
    var styleElement = document.createElement('style');

    // Define the CSS rule
    var css = "p { color: pink !important; }";

    // Add the CSS rule to the <style> element
    styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));

    // Insert the <style> element into the <head> of the document
    document.head.insertBefore(styleElement, document.head.firstChild);
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
x.style.display= null;

  }

  // Call the function to apply the style
  applyStyle();

  // *** in the REAL app, this script would just have empty contents and have a src attribute ***
</script>

  </head>
  <body style="display:none;">
    <p>testing</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this would be to add a loader for your page and wait till the page is completely rendered. I have added a loader and after the `applyStyle()` is executed, I hid the loader.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        p {
            color: blue
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        // Function to create a fake promise that resolves after 3 seconds
        async function fakePromise() {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                setTimeout(resolve, 3000); // Resolve after 3 seconds
            });
        }

        // Use async/await to wait for the fake promise to resolve
        async function applyStyle() {
            await fakePromise();

            // Create a <style> element
            var styleElement = document.createElement('style');

            // Define the CSS rule
            var css = "p { color: pink !important; }";

            // Add the CSS rule to the <style> element
            styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));

            // Insert the <style> element into the <head> of the document
            document.head.insertBefore(styleElement, document.head.firstChild);
            document.getElementById("loader").classList.add("hidden");
        }

        // Call the function to apply the style
        applyStyle();

        // *** in the REAL app, this script would just have empty contents and have a src attribute ***
    </script>
    <style>
        #loader {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: #000;
            z-index: 999;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .loading {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border: 10px solid #fff0;
            border-top: 10px solid #fff;
            border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
            border-radius: 50%;
            animation: spin 2s infinite;
        }

        @keyframes spin {
            0% {
                transform: rotate(360deg);
            }

            100% {
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }
        }

        #loader.hidden {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="loader">
        <div class="loading"></div>
    </div>
    <p>testing</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>p {color: white}</style>

    <script>
      // Function to create a fake promise that resolves after 3 seconds
      async function fakePromise() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          setTimeout(resolve, 6000); // Resolve after 3 seconds
        });
      }

      // Use async/await to wait for the fake promise to resolve
      async function applyStyle() {
        await fakePromise();
        
        // Create a <style> element
        var styleElement = document.createElement('style');
        
        // Define the CSS rule
        var css = "p { color: pink !important; }";
        
        // Add the CSS rule to the <style> element
        styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
        
        // Insert the <style> element into the <head> of the document
        document.head.insertBefore(styleElement, document.head.firstChild);
      }

      // Wait for the "load" event to fire before calling applyStyle
      window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
        applyStyle();
      });

// Wait for the "load" event to fire before calling applyStyle and redirecting
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
  applyStyle();
  // Redirect to another page
  window.location.href = "https://example.com/your_redirect_Page_here";
});

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>testing</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but if we look at your example of applying the style (and not redirecting), it looks like the DOM loads before the promise resolves. Do you know a fix for this, so that the body only renders after the promise resolves (and the styles are applied)? I've made this demo: https://playcode.io/1783540