# Foundation 5 possible Bug : Uncaught TypeError: Layer must be a document node foundation.min.js:8

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I'm trying for the first time the Zurb Foundation 5 framework and I got this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Layer must be a document node foundation.min.js:8"

This happened because I had this in the :

`<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/foundation.min.js"></script>`

When I moved it to the body, the error is gone.

Why? am I missing something about javascript or is it a bug?

Comment: Read the docs: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html it tells you to place jquery and foundation before the body tag.

Comment: Before the ***closing*** body tag. But there are other options if you're forced to keep the JS in the head: see below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a **bug** that was resolved [in a recent commit](https://github.com/seantimm/foundation/commit/d98a7d540ee764e79d2dbadc0e2617964207a53c) that was [merged into what will be v5.0.3](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/commit/12ad42f8a5c6566df009096d6b6158b3df4e0b9d). Just include that commit manually or wait until the v5.0.3 release and you should be good to go.

**What's Going On**

Foundation now initializes immediately from wherever you load the file instead of waiting for the DOM to load. For increased mobile performance, Foundation 5 embeds a library called [`FastClick`](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) and tries to attach it to `document.body` on initialization, so if you execute the JavaScript in the `<head />` before the `<body />` has rendered, FastClick throws that error.

If you're using [Rails Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/), [Flask Turbolinks](https://github.com/lepture/flask-turbolinks), or any similar library that replaces the `<body />` dynamically, you'll need to keep your JS in the `<head />`

Answer (score 2):

Most probably your html file was something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>

<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/foundation.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And you got the error like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Layer must be a document node 
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'foundation'
```

You have to move `<script>` line which includes foundation.js to body part, just before other script tag. As it is described in documentation. It is not a bug but it is a matter of script ordering/execution and dependencies. See [load and execute order of scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts) and other linked Q&A. And jquery.js has to be included before foundation.js library.

Comment: Not really. The body was empty.