# angular module: order of loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I fount out in the official angularjs documents that

`angular.module('foo', [])` makes the definition of foo module, and

`angular.module('foo')` is calling (not making) foo module.

But I could not start my app when I wrote the code below,

app/controllers/file1.js

`var app = angular.module('app.controller', []);`

app/controllers/file2.js

`var app = angular.module('app.controller');`

and, it worked when I only changed those two declarations:

app/controllers/file1.js

`var app = angular.module('app.controller');`

app/controllers/file2.js

`var app = angular.module('app.controller', []);`

so... I am wondering that

- how the order of loading module is decided
- how should I do when I want to use same module on two or more files

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward: you must **create** the module **before** to be able to use it.

It's clearly a bad idea to create it in a controller file; use a separate file for this purpose, in which you will also be able to make the global configuration (`myModule.config()`) of your project, for instance. In your case:

```
/** In "app/controller.js" **/
angular.module('app.controller', []); // Creation of the module

/** In "app/controllers/file1.js" **/
/** In "app/controllers/file2.js" **/
angular.module('app.controller'); // Use of the (already existing) module
```

The file `app/controller.js` should be called first. Then, the order of the other files doesn't matter.

Comment: thanks. May I ask an additional question? 
I don't know how to call "app/controller.js" first in your example. Could you show some examples about it? AngularJS doesn't have main method, so it can be in the global configuration...?

Comment: Just put the tags `<script>` in the right order. [Scripts are loaded in the order encountered in the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts).

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I didn't realize it because I was using brunch.io (and its seed for angularjs) and I didn't need to write script tags. I 'll check the brunch.io's config. Thank you for helpful infomations.