# right way to add dependency into a angular.module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var myTestApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);
myTestApp
  .controller('MyController',
    ['$scope', 'EmailParser',
      function($scope, EmailParser) {
    ...}]);

angular.module('myApp', ['emailParser'])
  .controller('MyController',
    ['$scope', 'EmailParser',
      function($scope, EmailParser) {...}]);
```

I will encounter error when I use above method to add the dependency of `emailParser` into an agular module. What is the right way to do it?
NOTE: `emailParser` is declared in the actual code

**Update**

I don't want certain controller have access to email Parser module. I am not sure if this kind of thinking is right. What is the best practice for adding dependency after the declaration of module at the beginning? Am I going the right way to do it?

The error I received was

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MyController' is not a function, got undefined
```

I am sure if my way of thinking how it work is right. Is that I want add emailParser into the module not a good idea, or not a good practice?

Thank You

Comment: [Don't confound module declaration and module utilisation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982763/angular-module-order-of-loading/23983080#23983080). That's said, what's your error?

Comment: @Blackhole I realize it did not fix the issue, so I updated the question just now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must add dependencies when you first declare your module. Any reason just this isn't working:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['emailParser'])
  .controller('MyController',
    ['$scope', 'EmailParser',
      function($scope, EmailParser) {...}]);
```

Comment: that may cause the problem. I did not add dependency at the beginning it was [] for angular .module.

Comment: why are you declaring your module twice and why can't you specify the dependency the first time?

Comment: so I assume then that in a single ng-app, angular.module dependency can not be..inserted after the declaration of the angular.module itself?