# Difference between including a Javascript vs keeping it between script tags?

Tags: javascript, html, web, include

I currently have a piece of javascript code that initializes a datepicker and I have stored it a js file. When I access the webpage the code does not seem to be working. However, when I copy paste the file and keep it within script tags at the same exact location where I had a  the code works. I know the path to the file is correct as I subsituted document.write inside the file and it executed properly. Therefore I think there must be some difference in the way code in a script src is executed vs inline js. I tried googling for information but none was helpful.

Thanks

As requested code sample below:

init.js:

```
$(function() {
var temp = new Date(); 
var now = new Date(temp.getUTCFullYear(), temp.getUTCMonth(), temp.getUTCDate(),  temp.getUTCHours(), temp.getUTCMinutes(), temp.getUTCSeconds());

$("#start_date").datetimepicker({       
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    controlType: 'select',
    timezone: 'UTC',
    maxDate: now,
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        if ($("#end_date").val() != '') {
            var testStartDate = $("#start_date").datetimepicker('getDate');
            var testEndDate = $("#end_date").datetimepicker('getDate');
            if (testStartDate >= testEndDate) {
                $("#end_date").datetimepicker('setDate', testStartDate);
                $("#start_date").datetimepicker('setDate', new Date(testStartDate.setHours(testStartDate.getHours() - 1))); 
            }
        }
        else {
            $("#end_date").val(dateText);
        }
    },
    onSelect: function (selectedDateTime){
        $("#end_date").datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', $("#start_date").datetimepicker('getDate'));
    }
});

$("#end_date").datetimepicker({     
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    controlType: 'select',
    timezone: 'UTC',
    maxDate: now,
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        if ($("#start_date").val() != '') {
            var testStartDate = $("#start_date").datetimepicker('getDate');
            var testEndDate = $("#end_date").datetimepicker('getDate');
            if (testStartDate >= testEndDate)
                $("#start_date").datetimepicker('setDate', new Date(testEndDate.setHours(testEndDate.getHours() - 1)));
        }
        else {
            $("#start_date").val(dateText);
        }
    },
    onSelect: function (selectedDateTime){
        $("#start_date").datetimepicker('option', 'maxDate', $("#end_date").datetimepicker('getDate') );
    }
});

var start_date = "${parameters.start_date}";
var end_date = "${parameters.end_date}";

var format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss';

$("#end_date").datetimepicker("setDate", new Date(moment(end_date, format)));   
$("#start_date").datetimepicker("setDate", new Date(moment(start_date, format)));

});
```

callingfile:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<script src="js/init.js"></script>


<div align="center">
    <p>     
    Start Date:  
    <input type="text" id="start_date" class="datepicker" name="start_date" readOnly="true">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    End Date: 
    <input type="text" id="end_date" class="datepicker" name="end_date" readOnly="true">
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: code samples please!   http://sscce.org/

Comment: look for errors in your console.

Comment: I suspect you are trying to access the date picker stuff before onload has triggered in your script.

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference wether you include a file or write the code in script tags in the same place, so you're probably doing something else wrong, `document.write` sound like one of those things.

Comment: Where and how does jquery get loaded on your page and where is the datetimepicker function defined?

Comment: There is another file that loads jquery before this one is executed. I'm sure it works properly as my code works if I simply copy paste the script and place it where the script src tag is between <script> tags.

Comment: Dependencies in javascript are tricky, and the order in which the scripts are run tends to matter a lot. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts

Comment: The Elements have to exist on the page before your script tags unless your script in running onload. Then you'll want the code in your `<head>`, internal or external.

Comment: If it does not work in the external JavaScript file than that probably means the file path is wrong. The console should tell you that.