# External javascript file working but not calling functions

Tags: javascript, html

My index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8" />
    <title> My Title </title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src= "myScript.js"> </script>
    <script>
        myFunction();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

myScript.js file:

```
<!--

function myFunction(){
    alert("external file worked");
}

// -->
```

When I run this - no alert pops up. But if I change myScript.js to this:

```
<!--
    alert("external file worked");
// -->
```

It alerts just fine. So my problem is in the function call, but I cannot see anything wrong with it. Anyone with sharper eyes than me can help?

Comment: You don't have a function named `myFunction`.  Change `myFunction` to `class`, or change `class` to `myFunction`.

Comment: Inside a JavaScript file you don't need `<!--` and `//-->`.

Comment: Sorry Rick that was an editing error when I pasted it for questioning here - it's fixed now. Those two match in the original file.

Comment: There's a big difference between using a reserved word "class" and "myFunction"; the former gives an error.

Comment: HTML comments are not recognized on a `.js` file.

Comment: The code now works as-is for me, even with the HTML comments.  Are both files in the same folder?

Comment: Are you really doing `alert("external file worked")` in `myFunction()` or is that just a crude example?

Comment: Rick - yes they are in the same file. PHPglue - I'm just trying to get some verification that the html and javascript files are communicating.

Comment: @PHPglue, I thought the same thing you did re HTML comments, but I tried it as-is, and the HTML comment tags were ignored in Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Comment: You run into a problem with `<script>` tag placement when you're getting Elements that haven't been created yet. Some older Browsers cannot get the `<body>` from a script tag that is located within the `<body>`, instead of the `<head>` `onload`. For this reason you should (even though I haven't in the past) put your `<script>` tags in the `<head>` and run all of your code inside `var pre = onload; onload = function(){if(pre)pre();/* in here */}`. `pre` just executes the last `window.onload` Event. Note: `window` is implicit. You don't write `window.document.getElementById()`

Comment: Even your `onload` Event can be put in the External JavaScript file. Just put the `<script>` tag in the `<head>`, running the `onload` I show above on the External file, for pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point the myScript.js file loads after the myFunction() is called. Move the loader to the header or use the $(document).ready();

Comment: That makes no sense at all; the code as given in the latest revision should work as expected.

Comment: I'm glad this fixed the problem, but I don't understand why it would.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts:  "Inline scripts that come after external scripts have are held until all external scripts that came before them have loaded and run."

Answer (score 1):

Your original code (you've edited it later) was this:

```
function class()
{
    alert("external file worked");
}
```

Doing this causes an error:

> SyntaxError: Cannot use the reserved word 'class' as a function name.

If you change the function name to something that's not a reserved word it will work as expected.