# When does Require.js load files?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

What determines how early Require.js loads what ever files are required? Is loading executed as soon as the script is executed? After DOMContentLoaded? Something else?

I'm profiling a page I want to optimize and one thing I notice constantly is that Require fires off noticeably later than other scripts, what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JRBurke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126372/jrburke) hangs out around here sometimes, so he would be able to answer better than I will, because I'm just going to make some assumptions.

It sounds like you're using multiple script tags in your page, so if I had to guess I would say that the RequireJS dependency is simply loading later than other script tags. [Here's a whole bunch of info on the load and execute order of script tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts).

Otherwise, my understanding of RequireJS is that it loads things as they are needed. Imagine your RequireJS tag looks like this:

```
<script src="lib/require.js" data-main="main.js"></script>
```

If your `main.js` file looks like this:

```
requirejs.config({ /*conf */ });
```

Then RequireJS loads the main file, which configures RequireJS, and does nothing more. Later, maybe one of your files looks like this:

```
/* code, code code */
require(
    ['dist/module'],
    function( distModule ){
        /* code code code */
    }
);
```

At **this** point, Require would start firing off requests to resolve any dependency chains for `dist/module`. If any code before this introduces a delay (like waiting for something to load, or if it's wrapped in a jQuery DOMReady), RequireJS won't start loading modules until all those delays have resolved.

---

My situation is a little different, and it might provide some insight.
I have only one script tag in my entire application:

```
<script src="vendor/require.js" data-main="build/app"></script>
```

My main file looks like this:

```
requirejs.config({ /*conf */ });

require(
    ['dist/module1', 'dist/module2'],
    function( distModule1, distModule2 ){
        /* code code code */
    }
);
```

`distModule1` and `distModule2` kick off loading the ENTIRE application, and would fire off every request to get what it needs for the main view. As I move around the application, it fires off a request to get what it needs for subsequent views. I've actually used the [r.js whole-project optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#wholeproject) to compile everything into that one single file, so as soon as it loads, the **entire** application is loaded (300kb or so).

---

In summary, the RequireJS *library* is loaded as soon as the browser encounters the script tag. Code loaded this way is executed immediately. Assuming I understand RequireJS correctly, the library will then immediately attempt to load the `data-main` file - and I believe this is done asynchronously.

Every time a *module* is encountered, RequireJS loads them [**asynchronously**](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#mechanics). Any delay you're seeing might be related to that.

Comment: Yeah, due to the server-side being (proprietary and) modular, the main file on configures require. However, the behavior that I'm seeing is that the subscripts (that are later encountered) are fired off relatively early, but then idle for quite a while before any actual loading begins. Also, thank you for your answer.