# How to ensure <script> tag successfully load Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm studying to make Web application.

It seems like the script tag

```
<script src="...js"></script>
```

fails sometimes.

I've tried to find how to solve it but I cannot find the exact solution yet.

How can I ensure script tag successfully load Javascript?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: It can't fail, if file is online and accessible

Comment: @Marko Mackic really? What if the file is not online?

Comment: whenever your page start loading in browser than it already first load all javascripts than all html code.why yo need to ensure that <script> is loaded or not?

Comment: download the js file and give the that file path.

Comment: @KalpenPatel oh you live in terrible misconception

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi It can only point to a local .js file or a .js file online some where like a CDN. Either way if it's pointed to the file correctly whether it's local or not it should load. Is the file local?

Comment: @MarkoMackic But it seems like that there can be error while loading script? Sometimes the function I define in JS file is enabled but sometimes it its not.

Comment: @tcasey I'm loading the local script file. I'm serious. It's really happening...

Comment: @MarkoMackic I mean to say if you are putting js in head tag than HTML parse it sequentially. so it will load first. I have referred this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28635141/sequence-in-which-html-page-loads

Comment: What do you mean by "fails sometimes"? Can you include text of `js` at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 because it usually loads the file well. But sometimes, I cannot click the button. I'm using Sign in with Google account API. I define auth2.attachClickHandler in a separated JS file. Usually I can click the button but I cannot click the button somtimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a handler for the [`onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) and/or [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) events.

```
<script>
    function errorHandler(script) {
        script.src = "backupLib.js";
    }
</script>
<script src="someLib.js" onerror="errorHandler(this)"></script>
```

Comment: is there any reason this isnt more widely used? I've never seen this before but it seems incredibly useful

Comment: @MichaelMK Probably because most people don't use unstable links. It's more common for `img` tags.

Comment: @4castle Would you please explain how can I try to reload when it fails?

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi In `errorHandler`, change the `src` attribute on the `<script>` tag to load something else. Reloading a broken link wouldn't be helpful.

Comment: @4castle Thanks! But seriously, my JS file is usually loaded well. Sometimes, onClickHandler I attached in my JS file is not loaded and I cannot invoke click event. So I may try to reload it, right?

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi Check for errors in your developer console (F12 on windows). If you have errors in your code, that would be different than a 404 error, which is what I thought this was about.

Answer (score 0):

Browser developer tools will helps you...

Load the website in the browser and open the developer tools then network tab, refresh the page.

There you can see the status of resources, what are all loaded in the page(images,js,css..), If the **status code** was **200** then it is **OK**.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

1. Script tag doesn't have an error event handler.
2. But we can use onload event handler instead like this :

   ```
   <script>
       function fileLoaded(name) {
          console.log('JS File loaded # '+ name  );
          alert('JS File loaded # '+ name  );
       }

       function fileLoadingError(name) {
          console.log('File error # '+ name  );
       }
   </script>
   <script src=".../jsFile.js" onload="fileLoaded('1')" onerror="fileLoadingError('1')"></script>
   ```
3. Make sure to keep the function first.
4. Even if there's error, the onload method will be called.

Comment: I'm not sure what your sources are. #1 & #4 are wrong. Run your code to find out.