# JAVASCRIPT audio application : Button does not change according to device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, web-audio-api

This is a html embed audio player with simple controls . i made this as an addon for my website. 
As autoplay is not supported in mobile browsers . The play/pause button changes according to device
ie: Play button shows up in mobile, Pause button shows up on pc's

The mobile side of the player works perfectly. But the pc side of it starts with the play button even though audio is playing in the background. ie. Else condition doesnt work

If the error isnt clear please copy paste the code here and see : www.htmledit.squarefree.com

```
    <head>


        <script>
            var playing = true;

            if (/Android|iPhone|iPad|Mobile|Mobi|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                playing = false;
            }
     <!-- THIS ELSE DOES NOT WORK . IT IS SUPPOSED TO CHANGE THE ICON TO PAUSE FROM PRE DEFINED PLAY  ICON-->
            else{
                document.getElementById('sound_icon').src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADAAAAAwCAYAAABXAvmHAAAAuUlEQVRoQ+2YwQ2AIAxFYRwncS3WchLH0YN6IWp/QhtCeJ5rgfd/W0JOg3958P0nDtBbQRRAgUYCWKgRYPPv8yiwlO1QcO1l/YXilefZi6yA18JeeTjAl52w0E3GAoGFsJDRk7FQDcirf3vloYgpYor4IsBlrnaC1b/pQhUxLISFPtqpVUtMYiYxk5hJ/O4Bq3swiaedxMq7aI8Y+S7UY3PKmhxAoRQZgwKRdJXcKKBQioxBgUi6Su4TGV3gMZ8LoyUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
            }



            function EvalSound(soundobj) {
                var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);

                if (!playing) {
                    thissound.play();
                    playing = true;
                    document.getElementById('sound_icon').src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADAAAAAwCAYAAABXAvmHAAAAuUlEQVRoQ+2YwQ2AIAxFYRwncS3WchLH0YN6IWp/QhtCeJ5rgfd/W0JOg3958P0nDtBbQRRAgUYCWKgRYPPv8yiwlO1QcO1l/YXilefZi6yA18JeeTjAl52w0E3GAoGFsJDRk7FQDcirf3vloYgpYor4IsBlrnaC1b/pQhUxLISFPtqpVUtMYiYxk5hJ/O4Bq3swiaedxMq7aI8Y+S7UY3PKmhxAoRQZgwKRdJXcKKBQioxBgUi6Su4TGV3gMZ8LoyUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
                } else if (playing) {
                    thissound.pause();
                    playing = false;
                    document.getElementById('sound_icon').src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADAAAAAwCAYAAABXAvmHAAABdElEQVRoQ+2YuxWCQBBFl0Rb0TJM9NiFdoAVOHSAHWAZZtoFoXagGZHroOghMHA+++G4JCT7mTvv8VjIzMCvbOD1mwQQWsGkQFJA2IFkIWEDxdP/V4EJHI7G3Fc1LM/iNgoWYCswhYNt97WZgcaOdmeYXQV1sKeKAbqdrwiS19vFnl0Jc6IWwHN7ayzayhZoK7z7uVQB3iUjSNWY8caHrZwA9GxVoq0Kl1q4BHjbClPKrl3ZyjlAz1bt89GCqMauN4APiHLsegfQjt1QAGqxGxRAI3ajAJDEbkwArNiNDgCj9oJv8vaU+9NxJBoAPNreUIKyhgVQ3txRAGDx+8aMcs7ZKSgAFn7CjyL41S7flAkC8LJLltcwryh2iQIAiy/QLiXHLkEBOruof0N7sBAtFqmWcgbAjcUoACSxGBRAIxaDAGjGoncA7Vj0BjD4X4vUTrkaz45RVwVR100A1I5pj08KaHeUul5SgNox7fFJAe2OUtd7AO2p3zFrWh4hAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
                }
            }

        </script>
    </head>



    <body>

        <a href="javascript:null()" onClick="EvalSound('sound1'); return false; ">

<!-- PRE DEFINED PLAY ICON IS BELOW -->

            <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" id="sound_icon" name="Sound" width="" height="" title="Background Music Controls" class="" /></a>


        <audio id="sound1" style="display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;" src="https://audio.clyp.it/3fnnuaiw.mp3?Expires=1488659248&Signature=01NkRScwYO4XaJO46JuNzPRR6cYQfcL5~rJzAu-gIoNoXkiMVZwazwT--amuqYvreLCSRFnFAFUvwR3v9Xaq1iB4~OmKSWqtF9mSm-CUB2Moqtie8wpGIRxTAkDHnfhN0sy45sINjwFP2xyVumld78USPuCBfNU3kgux69YG-yA_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJ4AMQB3XYIRCZ5PA" controls preload="auto" autobuffer autoplay>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When loading the page the script part at the headers is running before the elements where created at the DOM. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28635141/sequence-in-which-html-page-loads#28635195) to better understand how it works.

To have it working you can load the script at the end:

```html
<body>

  <a href="javascript:null()" onClick="EvalSound('sound1'); return false; ">

<!-- PRE DEFINED PLAY ICON IS BELOW -->

      <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" id="sound_icon" name="Sound" width="" height="" title="Background Music Controls" class="" /></a>


  <audio id="sound1" style="display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;" src="https://audio.clyp.it/3fnnuaiw.mp3?Expires=1488659248&Signature=01NkRScwYO4XaJO46JuNzPRR6cYQfcL5~rJzAu-gIoNoXkiMVZwazwT--amuqYvreLCSRFnFAFUvwR3v9Xaq1iB4~OmKSWqtF9mSm-CUB2Moqtie8wpGIRxTAkDHnfhN0sy45sINjwFP2xyVumld78USPuCBfNU3kgux69YG-yA_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJ4AMQB3XYIRCZ5PA" controls preload="auto" autobuffer autoplay>

  <script>
      var playing = true;
      var flag = false;
      if (/Android|iPhone|iPad|Mobile|Mobi|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
          playing = false;
      } else{
          document.getElementById('sound_icon').src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADAAAAAwCAYAAABXAvmHAAAAuUlEQVRoQ+2YwQ2AIAxFYRwncS3WchLH0YN6IWp/QhtCeJ5rgfd/W0JOg3958P0nDtBbQRRAgUYCWKgRYPPv8yiwlO1QcO1l/YXilefZi6yA18JeeTjAl52w0E3GAoGFsJDRk7FQDcirf3vloYgpYor4IsBlrnaC1b/pQhUxLISFPtqpVUtMYiYxk5hJ/O4Bq3swiaedxMq7aI8Y+S7UY3PKmhxAoRQZgwKRdJXcKKBQioxBgUi6Su4TGV3gMZ8LoyUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
      }



      function EvalSound(soundobj) {
          var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);

          if (!playing) {
              thissound.play();
              playing = true;
              document.getElementById('sound_icon').src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADAAAAAwCAYAAABXAvmHAAAAuUlEQVRoQ+2YwQ2AIAxFYRwncS3WchLH0YN6IWp/QhtCeJ5rgfd/W0JOg3958P0nDtBbQRRAgUYCWKgRYPPv8yiwlO1QcO1l/YXilefZi6yA18JeeTjAl52w0E3GAoGFsJDRk7FQDcirf3vloYgpYor4IsBlrnaC1b/pQhUxLISFPtqpVUtMYiYxk5hJ/O4Bq3swiaedxMq7aI8Y+S7UY3PKmhxAoRQZgwKRdJXcKKBQioxBgUi6Su4TGV3gMZ8LoyUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
          } else if (playing) {
              thissound.pause();
              playing = false;
              document.getElementById('sound_icon').src = "data:image/png;base64,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";
          }
      }

  </script>
</body>
```

or load after window is loaded with `window.onload`

```html
<head>
<script>
  var playing = true;
  var flag = false;

  window.onload = function () {
    if (/Android|iPhone|iPad|Mobile|Mobi|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
      playing = false;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('sound_icon').src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADAAAAAwCAYAAABXAvmHAAAAuUlEQVRoQ+2YwQ2AIAxFYRwncS3WchLH0YN6IWp/QhtCeJ5rgfd/W0JOg3958P0nDtBbQRRAgUYCWKgRYPPv8yiwlO1QcO1l/YXilefZi6yA18JeeTjAl52w0E3GAoGFsJDRk7FQDcirf3vloYgpYor4IsBlrnaC1b/pQhUxLISFPtqpVUtMYiYxk5hJ/O4Bq3swiaedxMq7aI8Y+S7UY3PKmhxAoRQZgwKRdJXcKKBQioxBgUi6Su4TGV3gMZ8LoyUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
    }
  }



  function EvalSound(soundobj) {
    var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);

    if (!playing) {
      thissound.play();
      playing = true;
      document.getElementById('sound_icon').src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADAAAAAwCAYAAABXAvmHAAAAuUlEQVRoQ+2YwQ2AIAxFYRwncS3WchLH0YN6IWp/QhtCeJ5rgfd/W0JOg3958P0nDtBbQRRAgUYCWKgRYPPv8yiwlO1QcO1l/YXilefZi6yA18JeeTjAl52w0E3GAoGFsJDRk7FQDcirf3vloYgpYor4IsBlrnaC1b/pQhUxLISFPtqpVUtMYiYxk5hJ/O4Bq3swiaedxMq7aI8Y+S7UY3PKmhxAoRQZgwKRdJXcKKBQioxBgUi6Su4TGV3gMZ8LoyUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
    } else if (playing) {
      thissound.pause();
      playing = false;
      document.getElementById('sound_icon').src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADAAAAAwCAYAAABXAvmHAAABdElEQVRoQ+2YuxWCQBBFl0Rb0TJM9NiFdoAVOHSAHWAZZtoFoXagGZHroOghMHA+++G4JCT7mTvv8VjIzMCvbOD1mwQQWsGkQFJA2IFkIWEDxdP/V4EJHI7G3Fc1LM/iNgoWYCswhYNt97WZgcaOdmeYXQV1sKeKAbqdrwiS19vFnl0Jc6IWwHN7ayzayhZoK7z7uVQB3iUjSNWY8caHrZwA9GxVoq0Kl1q4BHjbClPKrl3ZyjlAz1bt89GCqMauN4APiHLsegfQjt1QAGqxGxRAI3ajAJDEbkwArNiNDgCj9oJv8vaU+9NxJBoAPNreUIKyhgVQ3txRAGDx+8aMcs7ZKSgAFn7CjyL41S7flAkC8LJLltcwryh2iQIAiy/QLiXHLkEBOruof0N7sBAtFqmWcgbAjcUoACSxGBRAIxaDAGjGoncA7Vj0BjD4X4vUTrkaz45RVwVR100A1I5pj08KaHeUul5SgNox7fFJAe2OUtd7AO2p3zFrWh4hAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
    }
  }

</script>
</head>

<body>

<a href="javascript:null()" onClick="EvalSound('sound1'); return false; ">

<!-- PRE DEFINED PLAY ICON IS BELOW -->

<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" id="sound_icon" name="Sound" width="" height="" title="Background Music Controls" class="" /></a>


<audio id="sound1" style="display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;" src="https://audio.clyp.it/3fnnuaiw.mp3?Expires=1488659248&Signature=01NkRScwYO4XaJO46JuNzPRR6cYQfcL5~rJzAu-gIoNoXkiMVZwazwT--amuqYvreLCSRFnFAFUvwR3v9Xaq1iB4~OmKSWqtF9mSm-CUB2Moqtie8wpGIRxTAkDHnfhN0sy45sINjwFP2xyVumld78USPuCBfNU3kgux69YG-yA_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJ4AMQB3XYIRCZ5PA" controls preload="auto" autobuffer autoplay>

</body>
```

Comment: **Thank You So Much** for taking the time to give such an awesome explanation to such a silly question !!!!. It works perfectly. This is my first attempt at any html/js. Please check it out in action on my website  kzsh.weebly.com

Comment: No problem @SauravSuresh! Nice job on yours website. Good to know I could be helpful.
By the way, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.