# Javascript race condition?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

```js
var len1 = $("div").length
// can a new div inserted here?
var len2 = $("div").length
console.log(len1 === len2) // always true?
```

Is it possible for some rogue script to insert a new div between jQuery calls?

Comment: you want to insert a `div` element?

Comment: As long as both `length` calls happen in the same function: no. JS is single threaded (for the most part), so no other function can insert another div in between.

Comment: This might be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8996894/551093

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qqo54zr8/1/ - if a new element is inserted to the dom between those 2 statements the length will be refresed

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Pretty sure that's not what he meant, but I like the way you think :)

Comment: But, no... nobody else will be able to insert anything between the given 2 statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: You don't seem to be using `alert` or `confirm` in your code, and so the couple of weird edge cases in Firefox (which may only be in older versions) related to `alert` and `confirm` don't come into play. [This answer from 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734025/is-javascript-guaranteed-to-be-single-threaded) goes into those in detail.

But no, barring the above, no JavaScript code that accesses the DOM can be run between one statement and another in your code. Browsers run JavaScript with a *single* UI thread (and zero or more web worker threads, but web worker threads can't access the DOM).