# Use of gmaps.js (google maps api )

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, dictionary

I want use of [gmaps.js](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/) and i tried as following code but this don't work. what do to do?

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/65tza8h7/

```
<div id="map"></div>

#map {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
    }

var map = new GMaps({
      el: '#map',
      lat: -12.043333,
      lng: -77.028333
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the [Google Maps API js file](https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true) first and then the [gmaps.js](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/gmaps.js). Have a look at this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65tza8h7/1/).

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/gmaps.js"></script>
```

In your post, the gmaps.js file was loading first but the browser wasn't able to find any of the required methods from the Google Maps API file. You can read more on [Load and Execute order of scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts) at the link given.