# How to ensure the loading order of javascript before end of body tag in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, pagespeed

To optimize my website for google page speed I inserted my js-files before the end of the body-tag, so they don't delay the rendering of the website. This works fine in all modern browsers - also in IE until version 9.

The html where I embed the scripts looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/init.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tested the site via saucelabs to check, whether it works in good old Internet-Explorer 8.

Surprisingly in IE 8 I received an error message. I realized, that this error was caused, because my self hosted javascript was executed before the Google-hosted jquery was loaded – despite the fact, that I linked jquery first as shown above. When I host jquery myself and copy my script directly at the end of the jquery-file to reduce http-requests, the error-message is gone and everything works just fine.

Now to my question: Am I missing something regarding the loading order of the scripts or is there any other reason, that IE8 won't load jquery from google?
Actually I would like to rely on the CDN-version of jquery since there is no possibility to activate compression on my server and jquery is quite a big chunk of data. Btw the problem only appears in IE8 under Windows XP – in IE8 under Windows 7 the above shown solution also seems to works fine.

Comment: If you don't specify that the scripts be async, they load in order. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts Something else must be wrong.

Comment: You've said the tags are *"something like this"* -- well, this is programming, *details matter*. For instance, if either of those has `async` or `defer` on them somewhere, that would change things quite a lot.

Comment: Are you wrapping your jQuery code in `$(function() {}` in init.js ?

Comment: @MichelTomas: I'm wrapping it in a `$( document ).ready(function() { `. I know it's not necessary, because the second script should anyways be loaded after jquery. But since this is not the case…

Comment: @isherwood: when i copy the two files together in one file and host the on my server it works - so i think the scripts don't contain an error.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: No `async` or `defer`. Sorry for my inaccurate language – it's not something like this but exactly like I described.

Comment: What exactly is this "error message" that you're getting?

Comment: @pointy: The error-message is nonsense (the error is character 1 line 1 – object not defined). As I said, the script works perfect, when i host jquery from my own webspace.

Comment: The conclusion that that error is caused by the scripts being loaded in the wrong order (which does not happen) seems tenuous at best. Have you tried something like dropping a simple `<script>` with inline code to check to see if `$` is defined *between* the other two `<script>` tags?

Comment: @Pointy: No, I haven't. I'll try that.

Comment: @Pointy: You are right, jquery wasn't loaded at all. Changing https to http in the link surprisingly does the trick. I can't explain why, but that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

O.K., actually I don't understand what exactly caused the problem, but I found a clean solution:
As @Pointy correctly suggested the problem was that jquery wasn't loaded at all. I managed to fix this by changing the link from "https" to "http".

From:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Into:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now everything works fine.

I hope this answer will help somebody save some time. Perhaps someone can explain in detail why this modification is necessary.

Comment: Are you loading the page these script tags are in via `http` or `https`? If the latter, perhaps some time back you changed [IE8's default](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/22/https-mixed-content-in-ie8.aspx) for mixed content warnings to "Disable," which tells IE8 to silently not load insecure content on secure pages. The default is "Prompt."

Comment: Via `http` - really strange…

Comment: That **is** strange. Well, here's another good reason for using protocol-relative URLs. :-) `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score -3):

<strike>This is normal</strike>This can happen with IE8.

Either you host your own jQuery on your server, or you can remove the jQuery script tag and load the library from init.js.

One way to do so is to use the loadScript function as seen on http://en.design-noir.de/webdev/JS/loadScript/

```
loadScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js", init);

function init() { // your init.min.js code goes here }
```

This way you can ensure jQuery is loaded before you start using it.

Comment: Are you saying that a file loaded from another domain is inherently async?

Comment: Actually, the browser should load the scripts one after another - since I haven't activated asynchronous loading. Do you see any solution without using one more javascript and relying on the CDN? Because I can't compress the files on my webspace.

Comment: No, I'm saying that IE8 has some odd behaviors with CDNs and even with regular scripts. As I cannot check the page I can't tell what's the problem exactly, but I experienced this problem already with jQuery's CDN. And solved it by using one single javascript file, and loading external scripts from this single file. (btw, this allows the page to render more quickly)

Comment: No, IE8 is not broken (in this way). Whatever it was you were having trouble with before, it wasn't because IE8 fundamentally gets script tag processing wrong, or magically can't download from certain URLs other browsers can. That would be very well-known if it were the case, given how old IE8 is. Supporting, third-party evidence required.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: My momentary workaround can be seen here (but I'm unhappy with this) http://www.derkeim.com/new/ I have included the javascript via php directly into the page. It also works by linking instead of including it. I just included it because it earns a better page speed rating that way, because I cant compress the scripts on my webspace.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: seems that Michel Thomas was kind of right with stating that IE8 is quirky with loading assets from CDNs. Changing the link from https to http did do the trick. Why? Idk.

Comment: @Michel Tomas: Thanks for your input. I found a simpler solution to get around the quirkiness of IE8. I simply changed https into http in the link and everything works fine now.

Comment: Good to know you finally found out a solution that didn't involve many code changes!