# Why JS scripts are run in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

In my web app, you can open an iframe which load a report (similar to an excel spreadsheet). The reports open fine for a while (15-20 times). At some point, I will start always getting JS errors about kendo being undefined and I occasionally  get "Insufficient memory" errors in IE console.

As you can see in my HTML , the kendo.all.min.js file comes before the kendo.sage.custom.min.js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/kendo/web/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/kendo/kendo.sage.custom.min.js"></script>
```

When all goes well, fiddler shows[image]

But when i start getting errors, I can see the following : [image: scripts wrong order]

So for some reason, after using my app for a while, the scripts will load in the wrong order.

So I added console.log("all") and console.log("sage")at the top of each script. When working normally, I can see in order "all" and then "sage", but when I start getting the kendo undefined error, all i see is the "sage" log, never the "all".

We are using ASP.NET MVC and the scripts are in our layout file in the head section.

What could cause the scripts to be run in the wrong order ?

Comment: Well how is the order changing? How are you adding the scripts to the page?

Comment: That is what I'm looking for, I do nothing differently to get this result. Like I said, only by repeatedly opening the same report, at one point the scripts aren't loaded in the right order anymore. The scripts are all in the <head>, in the right order.

Comment: Is your cache on or off? Because cached scripts would load faster and depending on your cache limit, maybe only some would be, hence your result?

Comment: @Zze This time cache was off, but I had it happen with or without cache

Comment: Hmmmmm, maybe you could ajax them in linearly on load?

Comment: You mean load them with AJAX one after the other ? Like when the first is loaded, make another AJAX call to load the second ?

Answer (score 1):

Are all the script in the head section? If not then move the custom to the footer and load the custom script after the page has loaded, this will ensure that the custom file loads after the main file

```
$(window).load(function(){
var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "/Scripts/kendo/kendo.sage.custom.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
});
```

And for your answer, refer to this link
[load and execute order of scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts)

Comment: Yes my scripts are all in the head section and I would rather not play to much with the orders of the files since there are dependencies between them. The Kendo file is the second one (juste after jquery) and should be loaded before all others.

Comment: I understand, but It would help if you figure out the dependencies and move some to footer. or load them once the window has loaded

Comment: I think I will try to bundle all my JS together to make only one file be downloaded. Do you think that could be similar to your solution ?

Comment: if you plan to bundle also remember to compress / minify. In fact you should minify all js