# script to make <a> tag unclickable with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web

I want to make a script that makes  tag unclickable using JavaScript. I also want to use a function when you go over an  tag with the mouse that is gives an alert box that say’s its unclickable. I’ve been searching the web after examples of this but I can’t find anything with a separate JavaScript 
Something like this but not in the link it salve so I can use it on more than one link
If someone could help I would be so thankful

< a href="demo.html" onclick="return false;">demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do it on a script instead of a unique element, you can do something like this:

```
    var a_nodes_list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i = 0; i < a_nodes_list .length; i++) { 
        a_nodes_list[i].onclick = function() { return false; };
    }
```

```js
var a_nodes_list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0; i < a_nodes_list .length; i++) { 
  a_nodes_list[i].onclick = function() { return false; };
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.es">Link</a>
<a href="http://google.es">Link</a>
<a href="http://google.es">Link</a>
<a href="http://google.es">Link</a>
<a href="http://google.es">Link</a>
<a href="http://google.es">Link</a>
<a href="http://google.es">Link</a>
<a href="http://google.es">Link</a>
<a href="http://google.es">Link</a>
<a href="http://google.es">Link</a>
```

With `document.getElementsByTagName("a")` recover every `anchor` tag on the document. So just iterate through nodes and apply a handler for the `onclick` event to return false on every `a` node.

About the second request of your question related to use an alert box to say is unclickable we just need to modify our litte script:

```
        var a_nodes_list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for(var i = 0; i < a_nodes_list.length; i++) { 
            a_nodes_list[i].onclick = function() { return false; };
            a_nodes_list[i].onmouseover = function() { alert("UNCLICKABLE"); };
        }
```

```js
var a_nodes_list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0; i < a_nodes_list.length; i++) { 
  a_nodes_list[i].onclick = function() { return false; };
  a_nodes_list[i].onmouseover = function() { alert("UNCLICKABLE"); };
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.es">Link</a>
<a href="http://google.es">Link</a>
<a href="http://google.es">Link</a>
<a href="http://google.es">Link</a>
<a href="http://google.es">Link</a>
<a href="http://google.es">Link</a>
<a href="http://google.es">Link</a>
<a href="http://google.es">Link</a>
<a href="http://google.es">Link</a>
<a href="http://google.es">Link</a>
```

We just simply add `alert("UNCLICKABLE");` on the hover event of every anchor element.

Comment: Why would you re-retrieve all the `a` elements each time through the loop?

Comment: @torazaburo Was extremly inneficient, I think has better understunding reading the code in that inneficient way, but you are right, let's do it better

Comment: @frikinside Thanks !!!!  but I just tested the script but it doesn’t seem to work ??

Comment: @vde Maybe I don't get you question correctly? There's two code snippet in this answer. The first one, show 10 links with the executed script. That 10 links don't go anywhere because of the `return false`. The second one, has the alert on hover requested. What problem are you facing? Are the snipets working for you?

Comment: @frikinside Thanks for the script if I run it in my html file between <script> tags’s it works fine and thanks for this but when I use it in an external JavaScript file it doesn’t won’t to work anymore?

Comment: @code well It should work in theory. What might be happen is that the javascript file loads and execute before the a nodes are attached to the DOM. There's a few ways to solve this, use that code as handler for document load event or link the script at the bottom of the dom. Take a look to this links: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8716680/3382947 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/8996894/3382947

Answer (score 2):

Add an onlick with `return false`.

```html
<a  href="http://www.google.com" onclick="return false" onmouseover="alert('unclickable')">Link</a>
```

**EDIT (see comments):**
1. Find your element.
2. Set the onlick attribute.

```js
document.getElementById("link1").onclick = function() { 
            return false;
        };
```

```html
<a id="link1" href="http://www.google.com" >Link</a>
```

Comment: But a what to write a script to make the <a> tag’s unclickable

Comment: @zer00ne I want to use it in a script so I don’t need to put this in every tag

Comment: Use [addEventListener](http://help.dottoro.com/ljeuqqoq.php) That's what I always do when I want to modularize an inline `eventHandler`

Comment: @Christoph Is there a way that I Can use getElementByTag in stat of getElementById so i don't need an id ?

Comment: @vde I use that approach in the answer below. I think it suits better your needs. Check it and tell us!