# How defer attribute should work when loading several js files?

Tags: javascript, loading, deferred

I have the following example:

```
<script >
    console.log('first');
</script>
<script defer>
    console.log('last');
</script>
<script>
    console.log('second');
</script>
```

right in the head of my html, and I expect the console to print them in the asc order (first-second-third), however, what I actually see follows the order in which those scripts where placed (first - last - second).

I thought the 'defer' attribute will load the script, but will execute is until the DOM has been completely loaded. Dunno why this is not happening.

Regards,

Comment: `defer` is only for external scripts, not inline code, which doesn't need to load...

Comment: 'defer' attribute seems to be supported by only some browsers at this point. I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: some browsers? http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer says it's about all of them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `defer` attribute applies to scripts that are loaded via a `src` attribute with a URL, not for inline scripts.

You can see the whole HTML5 specification logic of the defer and async attributes here: [Load and execute order of scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts/8996894#8996894).

If you go through all the HTML5 rules in that above post, you will find that none of them match the situation you have because there is no `src` attribute on the `<script>` tag.  As such, it hits the last situation:

> Otherwise The user agent must immediately execute the script block,
>   even if other scripts are already executing.

The end result is that the `defer` attribute has no effect on script tags that are inline and do not have a `src` attribute.

---

If you want to execute that middle `<script>` after the other two, then you will need to either change it's order, insert it dynamically at the appropriate time or put the code into a separate script file so you can use a `src` attribute on the `<script>` tag.

Comment: How is it possible: "...execute the script block, even if other scripts are already executing"? How one script can pause another script for his own executing?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a different solution

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

> Since this feature hasn't yet been implemented by all other major browsers, authors should not assume that the script’s execution will actually be deferred. The defer attribute shouldn't be used on scripts that don't have the src attribute. Since Gecko 1.9.2, the defer attribute is ignored on scripts that don't have the src attribute. However, in Gecko 1.9.1 even inline scripts are deferred if the defer attribute is set.

I would suggest using a module loader like SystemJS to ensure modules are loaded synchronously.
https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs

```
System.import('./script1.js').then(function(m) {
    System.import('./script2.js').then(function(n) {
        console.log(m, n);
    });
});
```

Comment: agreed, the first line of that paragraph could be omitted.