# Can an externally hosted javascript file's code get executed parallel with window.load in a Page

Tags: javascript, html, execution

What is the execution flow of  the  external hosted javascript files with respect to the window.onload invokation.
Say we have below code in the external file:

```
(function() {

   console.log('logging1...');
})();

var func1 = function() {
   console.log('func1 invoked!');
};

func1();
```

Before the window.load gets fired,

1.) What is the execution flow or output of the above code?

2.) Is there a possibility for any code of the file getting executed after window.load?

3.) Parallel with window.load, can an external file code be executed.

Comment: This question is full of ambiguity for me.  I suggest reading through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload and asking a more specific question.  Also, javascript is not multithreaded.  You cannot run anything in parallel in js, (although you can use timeouts)

Answer (score 0):

1.) What is the execution flow or output of the above code?

Usually it is:

```
logging1...
func1 invoked!
```

There is no ambiguity in the order of function invocations here. But pay attention that `console.log()` is not standardized to immediately print the output. It could very well return synchronously without printing the given arguments in the order of `console.log()` function invocations.

2.) Is there a possibility for any code of the file getting executed after window.load?

No (apart from code in event listeners, timers and the like, of course).

> The **load event** fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images, **scripts**, links and sub-frames **have finished loading**.
>    (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

3.) Parallel with window.load, can an external file code be executed.

What do you mean with parallel? JavaScript is single threaded.