# What is the priority of execution of javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, external

I have an external JavaScript file linked by blogger. I want to change valuess in it. (css values assigned with JavaScript)

Is it possible to run the same code in head or body with different values assigned with JavaScript?
For example, CSS gives least priority to the external CSS stylesheets and assigns the properties which are given inside the file.

Does JavaScript have any priority system like that?

Comment: I thought CSS gave priority to the most specific selector

Comment: If your question ahs been answerd, you should accept one of these answers now, or explain what more you need to know

Comment: @Grezzo sorry i could not find it then but now I accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not priority, but *execution order*. Javascript is not involved in any sort of prioritising or doesn't have anything like specificity in CSS to even have a need for it.

Javascript code is [executed in the order it is included in the HTML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts) irrespective of whether it is inline or external js, although `events` makes things a bit more complicated, we can schedule code to be run later on certain events like 'load' event of `window`. So it is easy to make sure your code is run after theirs, but if they are say changing style from `onload` event handler, then you have to add your code to the same `event` itself. (Order of event handlers are ensured in DOM3 at least in specification)

But, have you tried `!important` in CSS, it can override inline styles and comes handy in some scenarios like this. But if you are able to remove the styles using JavaScript well and good.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript code is executed at the point of inclusion.

Html parser

- parse tags
- finds javascript
- (optional)download javascript
- stop parsing html

  - parse js
  - excecute js
- resume parsing html
- finds javascript
- (optional)download javascript
- stop parsing html

  - parse js
  - excecute js
- resume parsing html
- etc

Watch out for things like code that hooks itself to domready events, to only be fired when the document is done loading or other events, then it comes down to in which order they were registered.

There are also things like defer and async, which will make it load/execute in parralel to parsing(details and supporr vary per browser). 
But in most scenarios without heavily modified templates in google blogs the sequesce i laid out will happen

Comment: yea, forgive me to give answer to the question without divulging the plethora of asyncs, defers, script inclusions via scripts, scripts loaded by ajax requests and self combining javascript.  I try to cater the level of understanding of the asker.

Comment: Entirely possible to do that without stating something as fact which is, in fact, more nuanced. (As indeed you now have.) Also entirely possible to respond to a perfectly friendly comment in a non-sarky way.

Answer (score 0):

JS is executed as soon as it is loaded, so putting your script after theirs (either linking to an external file after, or putting it inline), it will be able to change things in the first script, but it may have executed by then.

You might be able to override parts of it, if their script wait for something before running, like the DOM ready event

Answer (score -1):

```
if you have tow function with same name, one in head and another one in an external .js file and both of them write a value in <a>, the result will be from the internal one, let's look at an example

<html>
<head>
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){   
document.getElementById("tester").innerHTML="Internal";       
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="test()">
    <a id="tester"></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
-------------------------------------
in myscripts.js
function test(){
document.getElementById("tester").innerHTML="external";    
}
-------------------------------------
when the page run it shows:
Internal
```

Comment: **Incorrect.** Whatever function definition is loaded _last_ is the one that is run when body is loaded. Swap the order of your script elements in the HTML (load your external scrip after the inline script), and you'll see "external" in your browser window instead