# JavaScript - order of execution of <script> tags

Tags: javascript

As stated in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts) and many other similar, the order of execution of `<script>`s on the page should be the same as the order in which these tags are defined in the html document.

I created a simple Java (server side) test app that allows to execute a request and wait specified period of time before returning a response (relevant code snippet at the bottom of this question). It has a simple API:

```
http://localhost:8080/latency?time=XXX&response=YYY
```

Example request that will return `console.log('done')` after one second (1000ms):

```
http://localhost:8080/latency?time=1000&response=console.log(%27done%27)
```

Next I created a simple index.html page (served by nginx):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>test order</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" async=false src="http://localhost:8080/latency?time=1000&amp;response=console.log(%27done1%27)"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" async=false src="http://localhost:8080/latency?time=100&amp;response=console.log(%27done2%27)"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" async=false src="http://localhost:8080/latency?time=10&amp;response=console.log(%27done3%27)"></script>
        <script>console.log('static script without "src" attr');</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

According to everything I read so far I expected the order of console output to be:

```
done1
done2
done3
static script without "src" attr
```

This is what I got (Firefox 51 dev console):

[image: latency requests 1]

[image: latency requests 2]

This is just the opposite order of what I expected to get. Am I missing something? **Is there a way to execute these scripts in the desired order (i.e. in the order they are defined in HTML)?**

As a reference, the Java part on a server side:

```java
private String latency(HttpServletRequest request) {

    long millis = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("time"));
    String response = request.getParameter("response");

    try {
        Thread.sleep(millis);
        return (response != null) ? response : "";
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you put `async="false"` (with quotes) does that help?

Comment: or remove `async` altogether

Comment: `async="false"` makes it asynchronous. Remove these attributes.

Comment: Did you put **async** puposefully?. Try without async attribute. Also try the same in different browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async) is a *boolean* attribute. Its value does not matter. Remove the attribute.