# ECMAScript : Some questions about Job and Job queue

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, specifications, ecmascript-2017

**this Question About ECMAScript Specification(ECMA-262 8th edition)**

These Days, I'm little confused about Job and Job Queue.

Here is Some Questions.

1: In ECMA-262, There is two kinds of Job Queue. one is `ScriptJobs` the other is `PromiseJobs`. So, Witch one have preference?
2: In ECMA-262, There is only definition of `RunJobs` abstract operation. I want to know when and where the `RunJobs` execute?
3.I executed code blow, In FF 60.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Title</title>
      <script>
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
          let x = document.createElement('script');
          x.innerHTML = 'console.log(3);';
          console.log('script start');
          document.body.appendChild(x);
          setTimeout(() => console.log(1), 0);
          Promise.resolve(2).then(console.log);
          console.log('script is end');
        });
      </script>
    </head>
   <body>
   </body>
  </html>
```

and it logs :

```
script start
3
script end
2
1
```

Why `script` element execute on excution context that created dynamically?

> c. Let nextQueue be a non‐empty Job Queue chosen in an implementation‐defined manner. If all
>   Job Queues are empty, the result is implementation‐defined.

forked from ECMA-262 RunJobs.
How HTML spec define **implementation‐defined manner**?

@Bergi like this?
    PromiseJobs : [] , ScriptJobs : []

```
ScriptJobs.push(something);   
// pop and run by Event loop   
// blow will happens while `something` runs 
PromiseJobs.push(anotherOne);
ScriptJobs.push(theother);     
//end of `something`    
//and in here, PromiseJobs will pop?
```

Comment: This should clarify https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0

Comment: @JaredSmith I already saw that video. But there was no explain with js specification.. :( I want to know with js specification..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which one have preference?

Neither. The spec [states](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) "*This specification does not define the order in which multiple Job Queues are serviced.*" The queues are only a tool to specify that *per queue*, jobs are executed in a FIFO order.

> I want to know when and where the `RunJobs` execute?

That depends very much on the implementation. In an environment like node.js, it would be called when the process is started - it's the basic event loop formulation. Of course there would be more job queues, e.g. for timers or asynchronous IO operations.

> Why script element execute on execution context that created dynamically?

Because the HTML spec is weird. Have a look at https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/ or [load and execute order of scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8996852/1048572) for an overview. The details can be found in the [HTML5 processing model for script elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#script-processing-model), which basically goes

- When the script element becomes connected (i.e. is inserted into the DOM),
- prepare everything and load it (if necessary) and do all kinds of checks,
- if the element does not have a `src` attribute and is a classic script (not a module) and is not parser-inserted,
- then "*Immediately execute the script block, even if other scripts are already executing.*"

Yes, this totally invalidated the ECMAScript queue model for browsers. Which is also explicitly state in the section [Integration with the JavaScript job queue](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#integration-with-the-javascript-job-queue).

Comment: >  The queues are only a tool to specify that per queue, jobs are executed in a FIFO order.   

this means, Whatever PromiseJobs, ScriptJobs, etc.. **the oldest one** will execute?

Comment: @EnvironmentSet the oldest job *per queue*. Not the order in which queues are serviced.

Comment: can you explain to me another one? check up please