# Call another script's function on Ajax.success

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a View in which I'm having a script tag and I want to use the function present in another JS file. If I add the AddScrollBar() in the same script file it works , but I want to use in multiple places. So I have it in site.js. When The page gets loaded I can see the script tag of site.js getting loaded.

View with script

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function LoadXyz() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ABC/Xyz/' + @Model.Number,
            success: function (data) {
                LoadContainerData(data);
                AddScrollBar();
            }
        });
        $("#navMenu > li").removeClass("active");
        $("#Xyz").addClass("active");
    }
```

Any ideas on how can I use AddScrollBar() present in site.js

Comment: Like you do. Just make sure site.js is loaded before you use it

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console. If so, please add them to your question. If not what leads you to believe that it's not working?

Comment: You should be able to place your js files in order of priority. Place site.js at the top of the list to be loaded before your other files. [JavaScript File Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts#answer-8996894)

Comment: I am loading the site.js in the Layout file and this script tag is in the View.But I think I understood what you are saying . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could call functions of other file (site.js in this case) if you insert the file in this way:

```
    <script src="path/to/site.js"></script>
    <script>
    AddScrollBar();
    </script>
```

you will be able to call functions and vars within site.js, but keep in mind that functions within site.js are not hoisted (As DonCarlos said in comments) so this doesn't going to work

```
    <script>
    AddScrollBar();//undefined
    </script>
    <script src="path/to/site.js"></script>
```

- site.js must be placed inside the document root, where browser can access it. So if we have a folder structure where the document root is **/var/www/** , browser will not be able to access to files in **/var**.
- If the file is placed in **/var/www/site.js** and the file who is calling site.js is placed in the same folder we could call site.js with just `src="site.js"` (relative path) or `src="http://example.com/site.js"` (absolute path)
- If the file is placed in **/var/www/scripts/site.js** and the script who is calling site.js is placed in **/var/www/**  we could call site.js with `src="/scripts/site.js"` (relative path) or `src="http://example.com/scripts/site.js"` (absolute path)
- If the file is placed in **/var/www/site.js** and the script who is calling site.js is placed in **/var/www/script/**  we could call site.js with `src="../site.js"` (relative path) or `src="http://example.com/site.js"` (absolute path)

Comment: I tried adding the site.js in the head of Layout file....and its getting loaded before this script tag but it didn't help. and I also tried loading site.js right before the the script tag...Didn't work

Comment: @Tina Are you setting the correct path?  keep in mind that site.js must be reachable by the browser

Answer (score 0):

you can create file script.js, copy code pastes below, run try it

```js
//create file script.js

var loadA = function(){
  console.log("loadA");
}

var loadB =  function(){
  console.log("loadB");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   loadA();
            loadB();
  });

 </script>
```