# window.onload is executed before the dynamic script is loaded in IE 8, 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

In my project, `window.onload` is executed before the dynamic script is loaded in IE 8, 9.

I have following codes.

---

**index.html**

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var eScript = document.createElement('script');
      eScript.type = 'text/javascript';
      eScript.src = './script.js';

      var eHead = document.querySelector('head');
      eHead.appendChild(eScript);

      window.onload = function() {
        console.log('all resource is loaded');
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
 </html>
```

**script.js**

```
console.log('[START] script.js');
```

and the console output is:

**IE 8, 9**

```
> all resource is loaded
> [START] script.js
```

**IE 10, 11**

```
[START] script.js
all resource is loaded
```

---

### Question?

I know that window.onload will run after downloading all the resources needed for the page. IE 10, 11 work as expected, but IE 8, 9 behave incorrectly.

I need an event listener that will be called after all dynamic resources (like script.js) have been downloaded and run in IE 8 and 9. I would be grateful if there is such a way.

What should I do? Thank you.

Comment: change browser :)

Comment: Try adding script tag in the body part.

Comment: Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts), when a script tag is inserted dynamically, how the execution order behaves will depend upon the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two matters: when the scripts are loaded, and when the document is loaded - as IE obviously for some reason doesn't take the dynamically injected scripts as part of the window at that time, while others do.

Anyway - `window.onload` controls the latter (the document loading). You can control the former (the script loading) manually. Just have the last script be `<script> start(); </script>`. As long as no scripts are `defer`, this should ensure your `start` function to be executed when everything is loaded. Or, you could attach `eScript.onload` handlers, to know exactly when everything is done.

Alternately, and probably preferably to home-brewing it, you can use a well-known and well-tested script loader like [headjs](https://github.com/headjs/headjs).

Comment: Thanks. I just modified the code so that it does not depend on `window.onload`.