# function not defined javascript onclick

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming so don't judge me. Trying to write code to measure length with latitude and longitude. It's showing this error:

> length.html:27 **Uncaught ReferenceError: area is not defined
>           at HTMLInputElement.onclick (length.html:27)**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script type="module">
                import LatLon from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/geodesy@2.2.0/latlon-spherical.min.js';
                function area()
                {
                var la1 = document.getElementById(lat1).value;
                var la2 = document.getElementById(lat2).value;
                var lo1 = document.getElementById(lon1).value;
                var lo2 = document.getElementById(lon2).value;
                const p1 = new LatLon(la1, lo1);
                const p2 = new LatLon(la2, la2);
                const d = p1.distanceTo(p2);
                    document.write('<br>Length is : ' + d);
                }
        </script>
        <form>
            First point<br>
             Latitude:&nbsp;
             <input type="text" name="lat1" id="lat1"><br>
             Longitude:
            <input type="text" name="lon1" id="lon1"><br>
            Second point<br>
            Latitude<input type="text" name="lat2" id="lat2"><br>
            Longitude<input type="text" name="lon2" id="lon2"><br>
            <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="area()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: write your function just before your body tag ends

Comment: See the answers to the linked question. Basically, the function you call from an `onxyz`-attribute-style event handler must be a global, but your `area` isn't a global because your script is a *module*, and top-level declarations in modules aren't globals (they're only accessible within the module). Instead, use modern techniques to hook up you handler: Get the element reference, and then use `addEventListener`.

Comment: Your script is loaded before the rest of the page. Search for "How HTML is loaded", or "Where to put script tag", or look at this answer - <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts/8996894#8996894>

Comment: @AndrewShymanel - Modules are automatically deferred (in effect), see [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element) and scroll down a bit to the graphic showing when and how scripts are loaded and executed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're totally right, thanks

Answer (score 4):

When you use `<script type="module">`, a separate scope is created to prevent name collisions. See [JavaScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) for more details.

You can make your function global by adding it to the `window` namespace, like so:

`window.area = area;`

Or you could simply use `addEventListener` in your JavaScript:

`document.querySelector('[type=submit]').addEventListener('click', area);`